# In-place processing with grep

Tags: unix, grep, in-place

I've got a script that calls grep to process a text file. Currently I am doing something like this.

```
$ grep 'SomeRegEx' myfile.txt > myfile.txt.temp
$ mv myfile.txt.temp myfile.txt
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to do in-place processing, as in store the results to the same original file without having to create a temporary file and then replace the original with the temp file when processing is done.

Of course I welcome comments as to why this should or should not be done, but I'm mainly interested in whether it *can* be done. In this example I'm using `grep`, but I'm interested about Unix tools in general. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perl has the `-i` switch, so does `sed` and `Ruby`

```
sed -i.bak -n '/SomeRegex/p' file

ruby -i.bak -ne 'print if /SomeRegex/' file
```

But note that all it ever does is creating "temp" files at the back end which you think you don't see, that's all.

Other ways, besides `grep`

awk

```
awk '/someRegex/' file > t && mv t file
```

bash

```
while read -r line;do case "$line" in *someregex*) echo "$line";;esac;done <file > t && mv t file
```

Comment: How do the awk and bash examples improve on the original grep, other than `&&` instead of `;`?  These still explicitly create a temporary file.

Answer (score 37):

[`sponge`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) (in `moreutils` package in Debian/Ubuntu) reads input till EOF and writes it into file, so you can grep file and write it back to itself.

Like this:

```
grep 'pattern' file | sponge file
```

Comment: I like this but unfortunately not installed by default in many distros.

Answer (score 4):

No, in general it can't be done in Unix like this. You can only create/truncate (with >) or append to a file (with >>). Once truncated, the old contents would be lost.

Answer (score 4):

In general, this can't be done.  But Perl has the `-i` switch:

```
perl -i -ne 'print if /SomeRegEx/' myfile.txt
```

Writing `-i.bak` will cause the original to be saved in `myfile.txt.bak`.

(Of course internally, Perl just does basically what you're already doing -- there's no special magic involved.)

Comment: got it while I was looking it up -- +1 for your speed

Answer (score 2):

Most installations of `sed` can do in-place editing, check the man page, you probably want the `-i` flag.

Answer (score 1):

To edit file in-place using vim-way, try:

```
$ ex -s +'%!grep foo' -cxa myfile.txt
```

Alternatively use [`sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7573368/55075) or [`gawk`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/55075).

Answer (score -1):

Store in a variable and then assign it to the original file:

```
A=$(cat aux.log | grep 'Something') && echo "${A}" > aux.log
```

Comment: Did you actually try this command? The `>` redirect truncates the input file before the `cat` command can read any input.

Comment: Hi, please avoid providing code only answers. Try to include an explanation of why the code/command you proposed solves the problem, or what caused it in the first place so the OP or someone with a similar problem can understand what to do.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at my slides "Field Guide To the Perl Command-Line Options" at http://petdance.com/perl/command-line-options.pdf for more ideas on what you can do in place with Perl.

Answer (score -3):

> cat myfile.txt | grep 'sometext' > myfile.txt

This will find sometext in myfile.txt and save it back to myfile.txt, this will accomplish what you want. Not sure about regex, but it does work for text.

Comment: This will actually truncate the `myfile.txt`! Bash will open the file for writing, pass it to grep as std out and cat will read just an empty file.