# In-place edits with sed on OS X

Tags: macos, file-io, sed, in-place

I'd like edit a file with sed on OS X.  I'm using the following command:

```
sed 's/oldword/newword/' file.txt
```

The output is sent to the terminal.  **file.txt** is not modified.  The changes are saved to **file2.txt** with this command:

```
sed 's/oldword/newword/' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

However I don't want another file.  I just want to edit **file1.txt**.  How can I do this?

I've tried the -i flag.  This results in the following error:

```
sed: 1: "file1.txt": invalid command code f
```

Comment: What's the exact command you're using when you try the `-i` flag?

Answer (score 439, accepted):

You can use the `-i` flag correctly by providing it with a suffix to add to the backed-up file. Extending your example:

```
sed -i.bu 's/oldword/newword/' file1.txt
```

Will give you two files: one with the name `file1.txt` that contains the substitution, and one with the name `file1.txt.bu` that has the original content.

**Mildly dangerous**

If you want to destructively overwrite the original file, use something like:

```
sed -i '' 's/oldword/newword/' file1.txt
      ^ note the space
```

Because of the way the line gets parsed, a space is required between the option flag and its argument *because the argument is zero-length.*

Other than possibly trashing your original, I’m not aware of any further dangers of tricking sed this way. It should be noted, however, that if this invocation of `sed` is part of a script, The Unix Way™ would (IMHO) be to use `sed` non-destructively, test that it exited cleanly, and only then remove the extraneous file.

Comment: You're right I was omitting the extension after the -i flag.  Is `-i''` dangerous for any reason other than potentially messing up the original file (and having no back-up)?

Comment: According to the `sed` man page if you run out of disk space on the device you could corrupt a file mid-stride and have a bad output result. If you are working under local source control `sed -i ""` without backups should be fine most of the time (or just `git init && git add -A . && git commit -m 'backup'` prior to running sed in `-i` mode).

Comment: I found the mildly dangerous bit particularly useful. +1

Comment: BSD sed requires that there be no space after the -i flag. So, `-i''` is valid, but `-i ''` is not.

Comment: Argh! BSD sed is ignoring the '\n' character and printing 'n' instead! Im just going to replace BSD sed with GNU sed on my mac!

Comment: How would it be to replace the strings oldword to newword in all files for the whole folder?

Comment: I don't think you're tricking sed. Its man page mentions using a zero-length argument to avoid creating a backup file: *If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved. It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.*

Comment: A `g` at the end `s/oldword/newword/g` is required if multiple `oldword` in the same line needs to be replaced. Without `g`, only the first `oldword` in any line is replaced.

Comment: I've been writing scripts which are meant to run under GIT Bash (Windows) and on Mac.
They guys testing the scripts on Mac, find that the -i '', in-place edit option, just causes backup files to be created, ending with double quotes - bizarre!

Answer (score 40):

The `-i` flag probably doesn't work for you, because you followed an example for [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) while macOS uses [BSD sed](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1) and they have a slightly different syntax.

All the other answers tell you how to correct the syntax to work with BSD sed. The alternative is to install GNU sed on your macOS with:

```
brew install gsed
```

and then use it instead of the `sed` version shipped with macOS (note the `g` prefix), e.g:

```bash
gsed -i 's/oldword/newword/' file1.txt
```

---

If you want GNU sed commands to be always portable to your macOS, you could prepend "gnubin" directory to your path, by adding something like this to your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` file (run `brew info gsed` to see what exactly you need to do):

```bash
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

and from then on the GNU sed becomes your default sed and you can simply run:

```bash
sed -i 's/oldword/newword/' file1.txt
```

Comment: I've aliased sed to gsed in my shell config. That does work. Are there advantages to your solution?

Answer (score 26):

I've similar problem with MacOS

```
sed -i '' 's/oldword/newword/' file1.txt
```

doesn't works, but

```
sed -i"any_symbol" 's/oldword/newword/' file1.txt
```

works well.

Comment: This is now the other way around. `sed -i '' <file>` works but `sed -i'' <file>` no longer works

Answer (score 9):

```
sed -i -- "s/https/http/g" file.txt
```

Comment: When I try that on mac, I get an error that says "sed: -i may not be used with stdin".

Comment: On my macOS (10.15.6), the `--` seems to work, but in fact it creates a `file.txt--` backup file, which must then be manually removed, so this solution is not better than the accepted one. And the `--` is misleading, as if the option were acting like GNU tools which treat it differently.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `-i''` (`--in-place`) for `sed` as already suggested. See: [The `-i` in-place argument](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-62h), however note that `-i` option is non-standard FreeBSD extensions and may not be available on other operating systems. Secondly [`sed` is a **S**tream **ED**itor, not a file editor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021#Using_nonstandard_tools).

---

Alternative way is to use built-in substitution in Vim Ex mode, like:

```
$ ex +%s/foo/bar/g -scwq file.txt
```

and for multiple-files:

```
$ ex +'bufdo!%s/foo/bar/g' -scxa *.*
```

<sup>To edit all files recursively you can use `**/*.*` if shell supports that (enable by `shopt -s globstar`).</sup>

---

Another way is to use [`gawk`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/55075) and its new ["inplace" extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html) such as:

```
$ gawk -i inplace '{ gsub(/foo/, "bar") }; { print }' file1
```

Answer (score 4):

This creates backup files. E.g. `sed -i -e 's/hello/hello world/' testfile` for me, creates a backup file, testfile-e, in the same dir.

Comment: Same here with Mac OS Catalina. Passing both -i and -e separately (NOT -ie together!) creates a backup file with '-e' appended.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sh
sed -i -e 's/<string-to-find>/<string-to-replace>/' <your-file-path>
```

Example:

```sh
sed -i -e 's/Hello/Bye/' file.txt
```

This works flawless in **Mac**.

Comment: This creates a backup file for me in Mac OS Catalina with '-e' appended.

Comment: This is wrong for macOS. Please take a look at the "man sed" page there. `-i` requires an argument for macOS. Since you don't specify one, it uses `-e`, which results in having a second file with `-e` appended. `-e` doesn't exist in macOS, it is `-E`. So correct command for macOS is `sed -i '' -E 's/Hello/Bye/' file.txt`

Comment: A minor variation that works in my case. I replaced two different strings (you can add more I guess) with this command:
        sed -i '' -e 's/_tools/tools/' -e 's/_static/static/' test.txt

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt it is not _wrong_ but rather is a good way to have identical scripts run on both mac and linux. The backup file is an affordable cost, compared to maintaining different scripts across platforms; it is easy to find and delete such backup files too.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to substitute more than one different words:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/_tools/tools/' -e 's/_static/static/' test.txt
```