# sed "undefined label" on MacOS

Tags: macos, sed

I recently found out that this simple `sed` expression work fine on Linux or under Cygwin but fails on Mac with an "undefined label" error:

```
$ sed '/SUCCESSFUL/d ; /\[java\]/!b label; s/\s\+\[java\]//; /^\s*$$/d; /Compiling/!d; :label /^\s*$$/d; s/^/monitor: /'
sed: 1: "/SUCCESSFUL/d ; /\[java ...": undefined label 'label; s/\s\+\[java\]//; /^\s*$$/d; /Compiling/!d; :label /^\s*$$/d; s/^/monitor: /'
```

`sed` on MacOS is a BSD variant with different options than the GNU counterpart. However `man sed` clearly indicates the MacOS version of `sed` supports labels, so why this error, and most important how to solve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name of the label terminates with the first literal newline, not at the semi-colon.  There are two easy ways to solve the problem.  Add literal newlines:

```
 sed '/SUCCESSFUL/d 
    /\[java\]/!b label
    s/\s\+\[java\]//
    /^\s*$$/d; /Compiling/!d
    :label
    /^\s*$$/d
    s/^/monitor: /'
```

Or use multiple `-e` options:

```
sed -e '/SUCCESSFUL/d ; /\[java\]/!b label' \
  -e 's/\s\+\[java\]//; /^\s*$$/d; /Compiling/!d' \
  -e':label' -e'/^\s*$$/d; s/^/monitor: /'
```

Comment: This is true in label defining commands as well as branching commands which reference labels. I don't see anything in POSIX which says that these commands don't have to observe the semicolon convention. Why don't Apple fix these things? It's still present in the latest Mac OS on M1.

Answer (score 35):

A quick fix is to prepend your string expression with an empty string: `''`

For example:
instead of

```bash
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' text.txt
```

write:

```bash
sed -i='' 's/foo/bar/g' text.txt
```

This should work across different OS (Linux, MacOS, Windows)

Comment: perfect, but why does this work? Does it work the same on Linux as macos?

Comment: I think the first and the second command do the same if executed on Linux and mac respectively. The first doesn’t work on Mac but I’m unsure what happens with the second on Linux.

Comment: there's a whole lot of blah blah blah on this page - thank goodness you cleared up that the label needed be provided as an empty string in mac.

Comment: An alternative could be to use `-i=''` this worked for me (as part of a Snakemake rule) when `-i ''` didn't.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7573438/61109

Comment: This command doesn't work on Bash on Windows

Comment: However the version of @CorneliusRoemer works on both

Comment: @TomSmykowski it's not nice to downvote a solution by claiming "it does not work on Bash on Windows" where clearly the answer said that it was for MacOS. It was even in written in **bold**. Read better next time before downvoting!
Thanks Cornelius for updating yesterday. I updated it again, clarifying that the new solution should work across OS

Answer (score 6):

There are a bunch of similar questions on SO but most of them are due to the behavior of `-i` differing between platforms, so this is different.

In this case, the issue is rather simple: it seems like label references can only go backwards in the BSD version of `sed`, whereas the GNU version allows to use forward references. That is on MacOS, the `:label` must appear *before* the `b label`.

The solution is to rewrite the expression to either define the label before the branch, or in the case of the expression above realize the branch is a kind of "if this pattern is not present ... jump ahead". In this case the expression can be expanded to not need the label in the first place:

```
sed '/SUCCESSFUL/d ; /\s+\[java\]\s*/d; /\[java\]/s/\s\+\[java\]//; /Compiling/!d; /^\s*$$/d; s/^/monitor: /'
```

Comment: +1 and Good catch. It also helps to visualize the issue as indented code, instead of with one-liner-itis :-) Good luck.