# Sed command : how to replace if exists else just insert?

Tags: linux, sed

I need to edit several lines in a file such that 
if a line begins with (av or avpgw) then replace these with new text,
else just insert the new text in beginning.

How can I do this using sed ?

Answer (score 22):

You can do it this way:

```
sed -e 's/^avpgw/new text/' -e t -e 's/^av/new text/' -e t -e 's/^/new text/' file
```

This replaces the pattern with `new text` (s///) and jumps to the end (t). Otherwise it tries the next pattern. See also [sed commands summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-commands-summary).

You can also separate the commands with `;`:

```
sed 's/^avpgw/new text/; t; s/^av/new text/; t; s/^/new text/' file
```

or put the commands in a sed command file:

```
s/^avpgw/new text/
t
s/^av/new text/
t
s/^/new text/
```

and call it this way:

```
sed -f commandfile file
```

If you want to ignore case, append an i at the end of the substitute command as in `s/^av/new text/i`. Another way is to spell it out with character sets `s/^[aA][vV]/new text/`. But that is not `sed` specific, for this you can search for regular expressions in general.

---

Since the replacement text is always the same,
another approach could be to remove `avpgw` and `av`,
and then insert `new text` at the beginning

```
sed -e 's/^avpgw//' -e 's/^av//' -e 's/^/new text/' file.txt
```

Be aware, that this would also remove a leading `avpgwav`. So this might or might not be, what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It worked perfectly fine. Is there a way to make it case insensitive.  I mean Av,AV,av etc. should all be replaced.

Comment: @user1765709 You can either use character sets or add a modifier. See my modified answer.

Comment: @Dobler I don't know, maybe a different `sed` or another version. What does `sed --version` say?

Comment: what's  'sed -e t' mean?

Comment: @ChanKim As written in the answer: "and jumps to the end (t)."

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^av(pgw)?.*/replacement/;t;s/^/replacement /' file
```

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho good point. GNU sed also provides the optional metacharacter `?` which means the same 0 or 1. But if there is no chance of the string `avpgwpgw` `*` is fine.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it all depends on how much we can trust the input =)

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to replace the prefix part(avpgw etc.)and not the whole text. It worked perfectly fine, after a minor modification. Is there a way to make it case insensitive.  I mean Av,AV,av etc. should all be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is but a minor clarification to [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741542/olaf-dietsche)'s excellent solution [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13014199/12854372).

If you are using OSX (which for me, using Catalina, uses a 2005 non-GNU version of `sed`), and you try to use his more-concise semicolon-based solution (repeated below, tiny modification with the 1/2/3's at the end):

```
sed 's/^avpgw/new text 1/; t; s/^av/new text 2/; t; s/^/new text 3/' file
```

... you may get an error similar to the below, due to the use of the `t` command in combination with the *semicolons* [`;`] (which are themselves separated from the rest of the command by regular *spaces*):

```
sed: 1: "s/^avpgw/new text 1/; t ...": undefined label '; s/^av/new text 2/; t; s/^/new text 3/'
```

This problem, and a solution, is described in: [sed “undefined label” on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12272512/12854372)

Below is a version of Olaf's "all-in-one command" solution that works on OSX.  It's debatable whether the `\n` characters are really any better than just using extra `-e`s. lolz aside: **I'm mainly posting because I wanted to share the "root cause" of this problem so that people using OS X won't drive themselves crazy thinking that their `sed` version doesn't properly support the `t` command robustly -- it's just an issue of semicolons versus newlines, that's all!**

Test file:

```
bash-3.2$ cat file
+ cat file
something
avpgw something else
av another thing
text
```

Original command, executed on OS X:

```
bash-3.2$ sed 's/^avpgw/new text 1/; t; s/^av/new text 2/; t; s/^/new text 3/' file

sed: 1: "s/^avpgw/new text 1/; t ...": undefined label '; s/^av/new text 2/; t; s/^/new text 3/'
```

With newlines instead of semicolons:

```
bash-3.2$ sed $'s/^avpgw/new text 1/\nt\ns/^av/new text 2/\nt\ns/^/new text 3/' file

new text 3something
new text 1 something else
new text 2 another thing
new text 3text
```