# How to replace line if found or append to end of file if not found in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I referred posts:

[Sed command : how to replace if exists else just insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014055/sed-command-how-to-replace-if-exists-else-just-insert)

https://superuser.com/questions/590630/sed-how-to-replace-line-if-found-or-append-to-end-of-file-if-not-found

But none of the solution seems to be working. Can anybody explain why?

I am just executing the commands on the terminal by making that particular file

```
sed -e 's/^avpgw/new text/' -e t -e 's/^av/new text/' -e t -e 's/^/new text/' file

sed '/^FOOBAR=/{h;s/=.*/=newvalue/};${x;/^$/{s//FOOBAR=newvalue/;H};x}' infile
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve].

Comment: at least have a -i option

Answer (score 3):

Test case:

```
$ cat > file
match
miss
```

Solution in awk:

```
$ awk 'sub(/match|$/,"hit")' file
hit
misshit
```

ie. replace the first `match` or the end-of-record `$`, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/match/{s/match/replace/g;p;D}; /match/!{s/$/replace/g;p;D}' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ cat file
some text... match ... some text
some text only here...
..... here also...

$ sed '/match/{s/match/replace/g;p;D}; /match/!{s/$/replace/g;p;D}' file
some text... replace ... some text
some text only here...replace
..... here also...replace
```

*Note:*
Use `-i` for edit files in place.