# Sed command to replace a string which has a special character "&"

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Content of test.csv is:

```
XYZ,IN123
```

Here is my script:

```
Var1=IN123
Var2=A&B
sed -i "s/$Var1/$Var2/g" test.csv
```

This is my simple code to replace the content of test.csv, when the code finds IN123, it will be replaced by A&B.

So expected output is:

```
XYZ,A&B
```

But with the above code I am getting:

```
XYZ,AIN123B
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately you have been caught out by the fact that `&` has a special meaning in a sed replacement string. It is a metacharacter that means "the entire pattern that was matched". In order to get a literal ampersand, you will have to escape it:

```
Var1='IN123'
Var2='A\&B'
sed -i "s/$Var1/$Var2/g" test.csv
```

The single quotes are necessary to prevent the `\&` from being interpreted as an escape sequence in the assignment. I added them to both variables for symmetry.

Comment: Hi Tom, This was a sample content which I posted. I am actually doing this from two input files. First file has Var1,Var2 and second file is the same test.csv. Do you mean in the input file itself, I have to handle this? I need to replace "&" with "\&" ?

Comment: @JavaProgrammer if you want to use sed, then yes. However , given the full details of your problem it sounds like there are better alternatives available. You should edit you question to show a sample of your files and your desired output.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when executing the command: `sed: 1: "test.csv": undefined label 'est.csv'`

Comment: @Boris I think this could be due to the behaviour of the `-i` switch in your version of sed https://stackoverflow.com/a/69955786/2088135 Try like `sed -i ''` or pass a non-empty string to create a backup file with that suffix.

Comment: Thank you, `sed -i ''` worked!

Answer (score 15):

Since the question asks about how this can be done with SED, there is a less known feature about it that can be very useful here - the *delimiters can be whatever you want* as long as they are not in your replacement string.

So for the above you could do

```
sed -i "s|$Var1|$Var2|g" test.csv
```

..and can replace it with $ or : or anything else you like.

Comment: I wish I could give you +10, this helped me the most! Now sed looks clean and nice to me! Big thanks to you!

Comment: But... Correct me if I'm wrong this doesn't work on every sed statement like: ```sed '/pattern/i line1' file.txt``` but in the modifed version it will NOT work: ```sed ':pattern:i line1' file.txt```

Comment: on MacOS, it show "sed: 1: invalid command code f"

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to deal with regex and escaping use `awk` like this:

```
Var1='IN123'
Var2='A&B'
awk -v v1="$Var1" -v v2="$Var2" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2==v1{$2=v2} 1' test.csv
XYZ,A&B
```

Comment: Can you expand on this?  Particularly...well, the entire `awk` statement.  I see `-v` makes a variable available to the `BEGIN` block and that block is executed after the assignment.  Then there is the FS and OFS (output field separator) but what's going on with this part: `$2==v1{$2=v2} 1`

Comment: `$2==v1` checks if 2nd column equals to `v1` and `{$2=v2}` sets 2nd column to `v2`

Comment: Okay, I see.  What's the `1` at the very end?

Comment: `1` is for printing data.

Comment: I've checked this on Linux and Mac, this does not work as much as I wish it did.  Perhaps something changed in AWK since this post, can anyone fix this?

Comment: It works pretty well for me on OSX and Linux awk

Answer (score 1):

& is a special char, hence, you need to use a `\`
Var2 needs to be specified in this way

`Var2="A\&B"`

Comment: Hi Vargan, This was a sample content which I posted. I am actually doing this from two input files. First file has Var1,Var2 and second file is the same test.csv. Do you mean in the input file itself, I have to handle this? I need to replace "&" with "\&" ?