# Django 1.5. 'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5

Tags: django

If I try:

```
href="{% url post_content product_id=p.id %}"
```

I have this error:

> 'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in
>   Django 1.5, see the docs.

How to change it?

Comment: If you need to support Django 1.3 and 1.5 have a lok at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882491/django-release-1-5-url-requires-a-non-empty-first-argument-the-syntax-change

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Changed in Django 1.5: The first parameter used not to be quoted,
>   which was inconsistent with other template tags. Since Django 1.5, it
>   is evaluated according to the usual rules: it can be a quoted string
>   or a variable that will be looked up in the context.

So: `"{% url 'post_content' product_id=p.id %}"`.