# what's the new syntax of url redirection in a label

Tags: django, syntax

My version of django is 1.6.3

and i learn django start with a project which have a part like this

```
    #blog_list.html
    <h3><a href="{% url detailblog blog.id %}">{{ blog.caption }}</a></h3>
    #urls.py
    url(r'^blog/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'blog_show', name='detailblog'),
```

the process is when i click the one item of the list that blog_list shows to me, it will bring me to blog_show via the a label.

But i got the error message that says:

```
'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.
```

I don't know where the location of this answer in the docs.

So help me, tell me the solution of this and the right way to check docs if i come to the same situation like this or worse. Thank you!

Comment: I found the solution. But another error comes up with Exception Value:  

'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your URL name in quotes:

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'detailblog' blog.id %}">{{ blog.caption }}</a></h3>
```

Similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271747/django-1-5-url-requires-a-non-empty-first-argument-the-syntax-changed-in-dja).

Example in docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url). Notice how in the examples, the first argument is in quotes.

Comment: 'str' object is not callable . why this comes up? Is that any changes should be done with urls.py?

Comment: You're probably missing the full path to your view. What imports do you have in urls.py for blog_show? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668040/django-str-object-is-not-callable

Comment: Yea. I just figured it out. Thank you