# Openshift: Installing Django 1.5 causes Server 500 error

Tags: django, python-2.7, openshift, django-1.5

I have created a Django 1.3 application on Openshift.
I wanted to upgrade to Django 1.5. So I updated setup.py to install Django 1.5

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='<Application name>',
    version='1.0',
    description='',
    author='',
    author_email='',
    url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
    install_requires=['Django>=1.5'],
)
```

The server returns http 500.

If setup.py has `install_requires=['Django<=1.4']` it works fine.

How can I install Django 1.5 on Openshift?

**Update**: I can see a github [commit](https://github.com/iepathos/django-example/commit/82a2e477bb82658a42d7ba188c9cd098abcea394) where in the install_requires for Django is changed from >=1.3 to <=1.4 for the handling this same issue. But I still cannot figure out what caused that server 500 and how can we install Django 1.5 on openshift

Comment: Have you tried `install_requires=['Django<=1.5']`?

Comment: if i specify install_requires=['Django<=1.5'], the setup script installs Django 1.4.3

Comment: Have you tried this fork? https://github.com/ramr/DjangoShift

Comment: Let us know what errors you're seeing in your logs: https://www.openshift.com/faq/how-to-troubleshoot-application-issues-using-logs Particularly useful are any errors you see in your git push logs/output as that's where it logs build/deploy hook output (e.g., building installing Django 1.5 on virtenv via pip).

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/django-setting-debug-false-causes-500-error

Answer (score 1):

It might come from your code, did you check the backwards incompatibilities mentioned in the release [notes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-1-5) (mainly ALLOWED_HOSTS required in your settings.py)

It could also come from the `{% url %}` tag syntax change, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882491/django-release-1-5-url-requires-a-non-empty-first-argument-the-syntax-change).

Comment: the code works correctly on my dev machine with django 1.5. So I guess the code is compatible with the django version

Answer (score 0):

When i installed Django app on OpenShift, Django version was 1.5.1.  I think OpenShift install last version Django, because the condition Django  >= 1.4, that is no lower this version.

That is screenshot, when i installed app
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue : from your screenshot you're using **python2.6** ?

Try to use python2.7 with this configurations put on the **application** file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR']))

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mywebsite.settings'

virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR'] + 'python/virtenv/'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(virtenv, 'lib/python2.7/site-packages')

virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass
#
# IMPORTANT: Put any additional includes below this line.  If placed above this
# line, it's possible required libraries won't be in your searchable path
#

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And as refered by @Charles L try to set the settings using [allowed host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/setting-debug-false-causes-500-error)