# Error during template rendering in mezzanine?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am new to mezzanine. I have got the reverse match error from package.Here

Reverse for 'admin_keywords_submit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

```
In template /mezzanine/mezzanine/core/templates/admin/base_site.html, error at line 37

Template error:
In template /home/nyros/hs/git_br/mezzanine/mezzanine/core/templates/admin/base_site.html, error at line 37
   Reverse for 'admin_keywords_submit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
   27 : {% if hide_slug_field %}.slug {display:none !important;}{% endif %}


   28 : {% if singleton %}.change-view-save-another {display:none !important;}{% endif %}


   29 : </style>


   30 : <script>


   31 : {% url "static_proxy" as static_proxy_url %}


   32 : {% url "fb_browse" as fb_browse_url %}


   33 : {% url "admin:index" as admin_index_url %}


   34 : {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}


   35 : window.__home_link = '<a href="{% url "home" %}">{% trans "View site" %}</a>';


   36 : window.__csrf_token = '{{ csrf_token }}';


   37 : window.__admin_keywords_submit_url = ' {% url "admin_keywords_submit" %} ';


   38 : window.__filebrowser_url = '{{ fb_browse_url }}';


   39 : window.__admin_url = '{{ admin_index_url }}';


   40 : window.__static_proxy = '{{ static_proxy_url }}';


   41 : window.__admin_media_prefix__ = '{% static "admin/" %}';


   42 : window.__grappelli_installed = {{ settings.GRAPPELLI_INSTALLED|lower }};


   43 : window.__language_code = '{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}';


   44 : </script>


   45 : {% if not settings.GRAPPELLI_INSTALLED %}


   46 : <script src="{% static "mezzanine/js/"|add:settings.JQUERY_FILENAME %}"></script>


   47 : {% endif %}
```

And I am using django-1.4.5.

Comment: Hard to issolate problem without urls.py ... but ... this is 1.4, have you tried without quotes? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15373978/842935

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here the url https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/core/templates/admin/base_site.html

Comment: @danihp I have tested the without quotes also but it is not working regards dhana

Comment: be sure you have included generic into your django installed apps settings.

Comment: I have included my installed apps "mezzanine.core",
 "mezzanine.generic",
 "mezzanine.blog",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer from Josh [is here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mezzanine-users/IYTR-NrQNuY). The context including settings is sent correctly only with RequestContext() in Mezzanine.

Answer (score 2):

this is likely due to not including mezzanines urls in your urls.py

```
("^", include("mezzanine.urls")),
```