# Regular expression replace with single quote in sed linux

Tags: django, bash, sed

I was trying with regular expressions to add single quotes to a word, taking care if in the expression I have single, doubles or none quotes. I have this

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/{% url \([^\' >][^\" >][^ >]*\)/{% url \'\1\'/g"
```

Example

```
{% url something foo bar %}
{% url "something" foo bar %}
{% url 'something' foo bar %}
```

should be replaced by

```
{% url 'something' foo bar %}
```

But in case

```
{% url "something.else" foo bar %}
```

it changes to

```
{% url '"something.else"' foo bar %}
```

Single quotes can't be escaped in single qoutes, and the same with doubles/doubles isn't it? How do I do? Regular expressions are fantastic but dificults too. Thanks!!

The origin was problems with urls in Django 1.5

```
"Django release 1.5: 'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5"
```

I found an answer to change to double quotes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882491/django-release-1-5-url-requires-a-non-empty-first-argument-the-syntax-change).

But same problem occurs with single quotes, replace 'word' to "'word'".

Comment: To get good attention to your question, consider formatting your post properly.

Comment: Sorry, I thought It was clearly explained and formatted. I don't understand you what's formatting properly, It's my first question here but a site of reference always, also speak Spanish so I take the opportunity to apologize if there are spelling mistakes too ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following might work for you:

```
sed -r "s/{% url ['\"]?([^ '\"]*)['\"]?/{% url '\1'/g"
```

For the input:

```
{% url something foo bar %}
{% url "something" foo bar %}
{% url 'something' foo bar %}
{% url "something.else" foo bar %}
```

it'd produce:

```
{% url 'something' foo bar %}
{% url 'something' foo bar %}
{% url 'something' foo bar %}
{% url 'something.else' foo bar %}
```

Comment: +1 for the simple efficient code. Just a small info that this does not allow a simple quote inside 2 double quote (or the inverse) like `"don't work"`. Solve with 3 s// consecutive, one by case or complete with the `foo bar %}` "pattern".

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work to me. Sed command looks very powerful but too hard.
It give me invalid reference whith -i and invalid expression with -r. Also I want to look all files in a directory and change lines so I need find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i I understand
Seems still continue the same problem whith escaping the single quotes. Solve it using the command I posted, because haven't double quotes, but in the future I need to use it again, luckily there are single or double quotes, but not a mixture of both.
Clearly I still do not understand how the regular expression works well