# How can I remove all lines not containing `@` from a text file?

Tags: regex, macos, awk, sed, grep

I cannot get this, or many other combinations of this, to work:

```
sed -i '' '/@/!d' file.txt
sed -i '' '/\@/!d' file.txt
sed -n '/@/p' file.txt > newfile.tx
```

What am I missing?

file.txt:

```
1. Lorem ip@sum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2. Nunc eu justo quis diam tempus auctor.
3. Suspe@ndisse in nulla et tellus aliquet finibus.
4. Aliquam @quis diam in tortor euismod faucibus ac lobortis massa.
5. Aenean feugiat nibh lobortis maximus pharetra.
6. Sed pharetra nibh id est lacinia, non pharetra nisi molestie.
```

desired result after `sed` or `awk` or `grep` or `???` deleting all lines not containing an `@`:

```
1. Lorem ip@sum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
3. Suspe@ndisse in nulla et tellus aliquet finibus.
4. Aliquam @quis diam in tortor euismod faucibus ac lobortis massa.
```

---

**UPDATE**

Turns out there were funny line endings that `OS X` didn't like. The following worked:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < file.txt | grep -F '@' > newfile.txt
```

Thanks to @TomFenech for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Is it possible that we've run into an issue with DOS line endings here? Try running `dos2unix` on your file.

Comment: If you want to do it awkwardly though `sed '/^[^@]*$/d'`

Comment: May be also good to check if the commands without redirection nor `-i` work to you. What do you get in the stdout if for example you say `sed '/@/!d' file`?

Comment: @TomFenech -- you were on the right track indeed! The following worked: `cat file.txt | tr '\r' '\n' > newfile.txt` and then `sed -i '' '/@/!d' newfile.txt`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like your real problem was with your line endings but I think the best solution would be to use `grep` with the `-F` switch:

```
grep -F '@' file.txt
```

This prints lines that match the fixed string `@` (no need for a regular expression match here).

You can pipe the output of `tr` like this:

```
tr -d '\r' < file.txt | grep -F '@'
```

Here I am deleting the carriage returns, rather than replacing them with a newline. Assuming that your files contain DOS-style line endings `\r\n`, this prevents blank lines from being added to the file.

If your files **only** have carriage returns, then you can use this option to substitute them for newlines:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < file.txt | grep -F '@'
```

Answer (score 5):

you can do:

```
grep '@' file
```

or with sed

```
sed -i '/@/!d' file
```

### Edit

so your problem is, you added a space between sed's `-i` and `''`. With this space, sed (tested with gnu sed) won't think the later `''` is for backup.  Also if you had `-i` option, you don't need the redirection. It will always give you an empty file.

Comment: How does this differ from the OP's attempt?

Comment: @TomFenech If you meant the `sed` command,  I don't have `<space>''` after `-i`  and I don't redirect to `newfile` they are differences,aren't they?

Comment: OP doesn't redirect except in the example you didn't use

Comment: @JID check his edit. He changed his original question.

Comment: @JID well it may not be seen any longer, but OP had written `sed -i '' '/@/!d' file.txt > newfile` in his question when I posted the answer.

Comment: You all are right, I was editing a bunch. Apologies. Turned out it was a line ending problem.

Comment: OSX `sed` is BSD `sed` which differs from GNU `sed` in various ways including needing a space between the `-i` and `''`. Your `sed` command will work perfectly for GNU `sed` but not for OSX's.

Comment: @terdon I have 0 experience with apple OS. OP edited the question a lot after I posted the answer. at that time, no any sign is showing it is on OSx.

Comment: I did not mean my comment as a critique, these small differences between the sed implementations are a pain. I just wanted to point out the issue.

Comment: @terdon apart from the difference, personally I think gnu sed is more powerful. There are some gnu-specific extension/features are quite nice.

Answer (score 4):

You can also say: hey, just print those lines containing `@`:

```
$ sed -n '/@/p' file
1. Lorem ip@sum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
3. Suspe@ndisse in nulla et tellus aliquet finibus.
4. Aliquam @quis diam in tortor euismod faucibus ac lobortis massa.
```

Comment: How can I get this to print to a new file? For whatever reason `file > newfile` isn't working for me.

Comment: Could this be a Mac OS issue? I cannot get this to work.

Comment: @Ryan So you are in OS X? What Wintermute suggested should be the way, see [In-place edits with sed on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7573438/1983854). Note the space between `-i` and `''`.