# How do I replace empty strings in a tsv with a value?

Tags: unix

I have a tsv, file1, that is structured as follows:

```
col1  col2  col3
1     4     3
22    0     8
3           5
```

so that the last line would look something like `3\t\t5`, if it was printed out. I'd like to replace that empty string with 'NA', so that the line would then be `3\tNA\t5`. What is the easiest way to go about this using the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk is designed for this scenario (among a million others ;-) )

```
  awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{
       for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
         if ($i == "") $i="NA"
       }
       print $0
 }' file > file.new && mv file.new file
```

`-F="\t"` indicates that the field separator (also known as `FS` internally to `awk`) is the tab character. We also set the output field separator `(OFS)` to `"\t"`.

`NF` is the number of fields on a line of data. `$i` gets evaluated as `$1, $2, $3, ...` for each value between 1 and `NF`.

We test if the `$i th` element is empty with `if ($i == "")` and when it is, we change the `$i th` element to contain the string "NA".

For each line of input, we print the line's (`$0`) value.

Outside the `awk` script, we write the output to a temp file, i.e. `file > file.new`. The `&&` tests that the `awk` script exited without errors, and if OK, then moves the `file.new` over the original file. Depending on the safety and security use-case your project requires, you may not want to "destroy" your original file.

IHTH.

Comment: @orange1: added explanation. Are you using the `orange` data-science environment by any chance? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation. I am not, actually. Gave it a quick google too, and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward approach is

```
sed -i 's/^\t/NA\t/;s/\t$/\tNA/;:0 s/\t\t/\tNA\t/;t0' file
```

- `sed -i` edit file in place;
- `s/a/b/` replace `a` with `b`;
- `s/^\t/\tNA/` replace `\t` in the beginning of the line with `NA\t`
  (the first column becomes `NA`);
- `s/\t$/\tNA/` the same for the last column;
- `s/\t\t/\tNA\t/` insert `NA` in between `\t\t`;
- `:0 s///; t0` repeat `s///` if there was a replacement (in case there are other missing values in the line).

Comment: An explanation could be useful for those unfamiliar with `sed`.

Comment: An explanation of what this does / how this works would make this a useful answer.

Comment: I'm getting the following error with this: `sed -i 's/^\t/NA\t/;s/\t$/\tNA/;:0 s/\t\t/\tNA\t/;t0' file1`
sed: 1: "file1": invalid command code f

Comment: Try this: `echo -e '1\t2\t3\t4\n\t\t\t' | sed 's/^\t/NA\t/;s/\t$/\tNA/;:0 s/\t\t/\tNA\t/;t0'` . If it works, the issue is with the file or with `-i` option (see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573368/in-place-edits-with-sed-on-os-x here]).