# deleting and replacing string inside .php file

Tags: regex, macos, shell, sed, sh

I am having some problems with loading a php file and then replacing his content with something else.
my code looks like this

```
$pattern="*random text*"
$rep=" "
$where=`ls *.php`
find -f $where -name "*.php" -exec sed -i 's/$pattern/$rep/g' {} \;
```

This wont load entire line of text. Also is there a limit of how many character can $pattern load?
Also is there a way to make this .sh file execute on every 15min for example?

i am using mac osX.

Thanks!

Comment: Among other possible errors here (why storing things in vars?) you need to use double quotes to have the variables expanded.

Comment: @fedorqui what do you mean? can you post an example. Thanks!

Comment: `sed "s/$var/$rep/g"`.

Comment: aso these are the erros i'm getting : `last_stand.sh: line 4: = : command not found
find: -name: No such file or directory
find: *.php: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `$var="value"` is wrong. You need to say `var="value"`.

If you just want to do something on files matching `*.php`, you are doing it in just a directory, so there is no need to use `find`. Just use `for` loop:

```
pattern="*random text*"
rep=" "
for file in *.php
do
   sed -i "s/$pattern/$rep/g" "$file"
done
```

See the usage of `sed "s/$var/.../g"` instead of `sed 's/$var/.../g'`. The double quotes expand the variables within the expression; otherwise, you would be looking for a literal `$var`.

Note that `sed -i` alone does not work in OS X, so [you probably have to say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7573438/1983854) `sed -i ''`.

---

Example of replacement:

Given a file:

```
$ cat a
hello
<?php eval(1234567890) regular php code ?>
bye
```

Let's remove everything from within `eval()`:

```
$ sed -r 's/(eval\()[^)]*/\1X/' a
hello
<?php eval(X) regular php code ?>
bye
```

Comment: this kinda didn't work. I am in the same folder where .php files are, i ran this code with sh <name>.sh no errors but code inside .php file didn't change. its still same string it used to be before calling up this script. Any suggestions?

Comment: Give more insight on what you are replacing. Also try to use sed without -i for testing purposes

Comment: well, i tried to replace a string inside my php file. its eval(base64_decode) string.
`<?php
eval(....)
regular php code
?>`

so i want to replace eval string with space for example.
I know that this might be not most productive solution, but I am just curious. Somehow i used to replace some of the string, but not entire one, because its very long.

Comment: @Michael see the example I added about how to do such thing.