# How can I avoid creation of the extra file with `-e` while using the sed tool in a shell script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I am using `sed` command in a shell script to edit & replace some file content of an xml file in a osx(unix) environment. Is there some way I can avoid sed creating the temporary files with `-e` ? I am doing the following in my script to edit a file with sed.

```
sed -i -e 's/abc/xyz/g' /PathTo/MyEditableFile.xml
```

Above `sed` command works great **but creates an extra file** as `/PathTo/MyEditableFile.xml-e`

**How can I avoid creation of the the extra file with `-e` there ?**

I tried some options like setting a temporary folder path to `sed` so that it creates the temporary file in `/tmp/`. Like so:

```
sed -i -e 's/abc/xyz/g' /PathTo/MyEditableFile.xml >/tmp
```

But doesnt seem to work

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3640/in-place-editing/12529/portable-use#t=201610180932445369797 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573368/in-place-edits-with-sed-on-os-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are editing the file in place (`-i`), OS X `sed` requires a mandatory backup filename.

You can use -`i ""` to get around this:

```
sed -i "" -e 's/abc/xyz/g' /PathTo/MyEditableFile.xml
```

Comment: thanks a ton. it works. removing the `-e` does not work for me though. may be because I am doing the complex sed command actually. like so: `sed -i "" -e 's/searchcriteriawith="[^"]*/searchcriteriawith="'$new_value_frmSome_var'/g' MyEditableFile.xml`

Comment: I did not wish to include all this complexity in my question. hence had simplified the sed command in the sample

Comment: @NelsonP No problem. I have removed that portion too.