# In-place edits using sed on OS X

Tags: macos, perl, sed

I have seen multiple posts on Stack overflow with various solutions to this problem. I tried various versions of posted solution, but I can't get it to work.

I am writing a perl script where I want to

`my $fileName = "apple";
 my $newName = "banana";
 my $ tmpPath = "/etc/ria";
 ["/usr/bin/sed","-i ''",  "s/${fileName}/${newName}/g", $tmpPath]`

I have tried various different combinations of this (i.e.
`["/usr/bin/sed","-i''",  "s/${fileName}/${newName}/g", $tmpPath]`
`["/usr/bin/sed","-i", '\'\',  "s/${fileName}/${newName}/g", $tmpPath]`
`["/usr/bin/sed","-i", '\'\', '-e', "s/${fileName}/${newName}/g", $tmpPath]`

However each time I run this, it creates ria & ria''.
I don't want the second file, ria''.

Can this not be accomplished? Or is there some other editor I can use? I don't want to install anything (i.e. gsed) on my mac.

I am running it as `system(@command);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-place edits with sed on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573368/in-place-edits-with-sed-on-os-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `sed -i '' ...` does is to pass "-i" as an argument, followed by a zero-length argument (the empty quotes). The single-quotes are *not* part of the argument, they're just there to indicate that there is an argument (it just doesn't have any content). To do the same thing in perl with `system`, use:

```
["/usr/bin/sed", "-i", "",  "s/${fileName}/${newName}/g", $tmpPath]
```