# write to a specific line in a file from a command line in MAC OS

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed, command-line

I have searched a little bit and I found the answer in this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75803/writing-starting-from-a-certain-line-number-in-a-text-file)

but when I try to execute this command `sed -i '5ianything' file1.txt` it won't work and an error message shown :

```
sed: 1: "file1.txt": invalid command code f
```

also the same error message appears when I use the other command `sed -i '5i\anything' file1.txt`

I don't know why it won't work for me did I miss something?
is there any other way to do this?

## edit

I've tried the solution provided in the comments and i run this command, but unfortunately even this won't work

```
sed -i.bu '5i\anything' file1.txt
    sed: 1: "5i\anything": extra characters after \ at the end of i command
```

and this is my file1.txt :

```
1. alloha I want some cheese
2.
3. this is just a test and you know it
4. 
5. this line will change sooooo sooooooon
6. 
7. daaaamn, it changed I mean that line above me daaaaamn
```

## edit

after I searched a little bit in man page of OSX of sed I found this :

```
-i extension
             Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It is not recommended
             to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.
```

Comment: Are you using an up-to-date version of gnu sed? What does `sed -V` say?

Comment: @match actually even sed -V doesn't work in my terminal and I got error message "sed: illegal option -- V" I am working in Mac

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7573438/10957435) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Chipster no even that won't work for me

Comment: I've run this command to know the version of gnu 'gcc -dumpversion | cut -f1 -d.' and it printed '4'

Comment: Sounds like it [could be a Pearl thing](https://askubuntu.com/q/938389), but it also seems like [it could be a mac thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4247068/10957435), but the Mac one doesn't seem to be your issue, so I think I'm out of suggestions beyond that.

Comment: You need a new line after the \

Comment: @wobr yeah your solution worked for me but I need to added a backup or an empty string like shown in the below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BSD/Mac sed provide an argument for in-place replacement (`-i` option):

```
sed -i .bak '5i\
anything' file1.txt
```

Or to replace original file without creating a backup pass an empty string to `-i` (you should first test this without `-i` and verify it works as expected):

```
sed -i '' '5i\
anything' file1.txt
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing worked for me, I've tried both of them and the same error occurs :
`sed: 1: "5ianything": command i expects \ followed by text`

Comment: Yeah now after you added a new line it worked perfectly, can you suggest for me a document that explains why this happening in mac.

Comment: GNU sed is documented in https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html. A manual page for BSD sed can be found in  https://man.openbsd.org/sed (which is less comprehensive than GNUs docs)