# Replace multiple variations of a string using sed

Tags: sed

I would like to replace variations of a string using sed.
The string pattern is required to match a set of optional repeatable characters ("../") and a mandatory string ("foo")
For e.g.
../foo
../../foo
../../../foo

I can replace a single version such as ../../../foo using pattern which will yield using sed:

```
sed - 's/\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\/foo/foo1/'
```

=> foo1
but I want to extend to match any version so I get:
../foo => foo1
../../foo => foo1
../../../foo => foo1

How do I achieve this using sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's,(\.\./)+foo,foo1,' file > newfile
```

Note the `-E` option enables the POSIX ERE syntax and the `(...)` are parsed as a grouping construct and `+` is parsed as a quantifier that matches one or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern.

If you need to make sure the match occurs at the start of the string, add `^` at the beginning: `'s,^(\.\./)+foo,foo1,'`. Note that the comma is used as a regex delimiter here to avoid escaping the `/` char.

If the `foo` must be matched as a whole word and if it ends with a word character, add `\>` closing word boundary construct right after `foo`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/8bQw5Y):

```sh
s='../foo
../../foo
../../../foo'
sed -E 's,(\.\./)+foo,foo1,' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
foo1
foo1
foo1
```

Comment: this is great, any ideas how I can do inplace edit using expression at the same time? 
I tried sed -i -E [] on my macOS but didn't seem to work

Comment: @Rubans Just use `.bak` or `''`: `sed -i '' -E 's,(\.\./)+foo,foo1,' file` or `sed -i.bak -E 's,(\.\./)+foo,foo1,' file`. See [In-place edits with sed on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7573368/3832970).

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you could do it much easier form, just match the pattern and if its found then print the new value.

```
s='../foo
../../foo
../../../foo'
echo "$s" | awk 'match($0,/(\.\.)+\/foo/){print "foo1"}'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be:

- First creating shell variable named `s` which has value of foo mentioned by OP in it.
- Then printing its value by `echo` command and sending it as a standard input to `awk` program.
- In `awk` program, using `awk`'s `match` function to match regex `(\.\.)+\/foo` if mentioned regex matched then print new value `foo2` in this case.

***Explanation of regex:***

`(\.\.)+\/foo`: match 2 literal dots(together) with 1 or more occurrences follows by `/foo` if match found then print the new value.

Output will be as follows:

```
foo1
foo1
foo1
```