# How to delete all the lines which have blank fields with sed or awk?

Tags: sed, awk

I would like to delete all the lines which have blank fields from text files. How can I change the following code to make the changes directly to the files?

```
awk '!/^\t|\t\t|\t$/' *.txt    

AD  125.9    MN 124.9
AC  38.9     VG 13.2
AV  34.6     BG 33.0
GL  126.2   
CY  34.9    
CY  44.9
```

desired output

```
AD  125.9    MN 124.9
AC  38.9     VG 13.2
AV  34.6     BG 33.0
```

Comment: are you mainly asking how to change the file in-place? check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979548/in-place-processing-with-grep

Comment: What is a 'blank field' in your context? Please provide an example of your input and of the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -n -s -i '/[^ \t]* [^ \t]* [^ \t]* [^ \t]/p' *.txt
```

Results:

```
AD  125.9    MN 124.9
AC  38.9     VG 13.2
AV  34.6     BG 33.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your code worked correctly with the given example. But when it uses with my original files, it deletes all the lines from the files.Is there any other option for this?

Comment: @user1606106: This code suppresses printing with the `-n` flag. It considers files separately rather than as a continuous stream with the `-s` flag and edits files in place with the `-i` flag. When it finds a line with four non-empty fields or more, it will print them. So if your original files do not have four or more fields, they will be emptied. If you are able to upload some of your original files and some expected output for each to something like [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/), perhaps I can help you.

Answer (score 7):

alternative awk one-liner:

```
awk 'NF==4' yourFile
```

Comment: I don't have `awk`, but `mawk.exe` is `mawk "NF==5" myfile` possible on Windows if I would have 5 columns?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop with your original awk command:

```
for f in *.txt
do
  cp $f /tmp/mytempfile
  awk '!/^\t|\t\t|\t$/' /tmp/mytempfile > $f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your input this might work  (but it depends if there are spaces or tabs):

```
sed '/^.\{13\}\s/d' INPUTFILE
```

Or this:

```
awk 'substr($0,14,1) = " " { print }' INPUTFILE
```

Comment: I tried all the answers and none of them worked. I need to make the changes directly to the files instead of printing the output.

Comment: @user1606106 Add the `-i` flag to the `sed` option. `awk` cannot do that afaik.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your file has a max of 4 fields:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<5;i++){if($i=="")next;}print}' file_name
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
AD      125.9    MN     124.9
AC      38.9     VG     13.2
AV      34.6     BG     33.0
GL      126.2
CY      34.9
CY      44.9
>awk '{for(i=1;i<5;i++){if($i=="")next;}print}' temp
AD      125.9    MN     124.9
AC      38.9     VG     13.2
AV      34.6     BG     33.0
>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I don't need to print the output. I would like to make the changes directly to the original files.