# Save modifications in place with awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I am learning `awk` and I would like to know if there is an option to write changes to file, similar to `sed` where I would use `-i` option to save modifications to a file.

I do understand that I could use redirection to write changes. However is there an option in `awk` to do that?

Comment: In case anyone wants to have inplace save with NON GNU `awk` could use following link too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59243104/save-modifications-in-place-with-non-gnu-awk  fyi please.

Comment: Everyone should read https://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/ which addresses the topic of "inplace" editing in general, not just using awk.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

In GNU Awk [4.1.0](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.awk/browse_thread/thread/40ce7554f025c382) (released 2013) and later, it has the option of ["inplace" file editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html):

> [...] The "inplace" extension, built using the new facility, can be used to simulate the GNU "`sed -i`" feature. [...]

Example usage:

```
$ gawk -i inplace '{ gsub(/foo/, "bar") }; { print }' file1 file2 file3
```

To keep the backup:

```
$ gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '{ gsub(/foo/, "bar") }
> { print }' file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: Looks like the option may have been removed? With 4.1.3, I have "-i includefile  --include=includefile"

Comment: @Keith I had the same question.  I just tried it and it works on my 4.1.3.  `inplace` is actually a library included with `gawk` according to [iiSeymour's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16529730/2877364), so `inplace` is something that can be included as an `includefile`.

Comment: An important caveat here: the 'seen' array will fill up with duplicate lines from ALL the files included in the command. So if each file has e.g. a common header, that will be removed in every file after the first one. If you instead want to treat each file independently, you'll need to do something like for f in *.txt; do gawk -i inplace '!seen[$0]++' "$f"; done

Comment: Note: Since GNU Awk 5.x, the `INPLACE_SUFFIX` is now a namespaced variable called `inplace::suffix`. The extension will **fall back** to the old variable, but **not in versions 5.0.0 and 5.0.1** (5.0.1 ships with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), only since 5.1.0. But you can simply pass both variables to avoid any problems.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Good review, you're right! 
Your note was useful for me, thanks!

Answer (score 172):

**Unless you have GNU awk 4.1.0 or later...**

You won't have such an option as sed's `-i` option so instead do:

```
$ awk '{print $0}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Note: the `-i` is not magic, it is also creating a temporary file `sed` just handles it for you.

---

**As of GNU awk 4.1.0...**

`GNU awk` added this functionality in version 4.1.0 *(released 10/05/2013)*. It is not as straight forwards as just giving the `-i` option as described in the released notes:

> The new -i option (from xgawk) is used for loading awk library files.    This differs from -f in that the first non-option argument
>   is treated as a script.

You need to use the bundled `inplace.awk` include file to invoke the extension properly like so:

```
$ cat file
123 abc
456 def
789 hij

$ gawk -i inplace '{print $1}' file

$ cat file
123
456
789
```

The variable `INPLACE_SUFFIX` can be used to specify the extension for a backup file:

```
$ gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '{print $1}' file

$ cat file
123
456
789

$ cat file.bak
123 abc
456 def
789 hij
```

I am happy this feature has been added but to me, the implementation isn't very awkish as the power comes from the conciseness of the language and `-i inplace` is 8 characters too long *i.m.o*.

Here is a link to the [**manual**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk#Extension-Sample-Inplace) for the official word.

Comment: Shouldn't your 'first' example be more like: ```awk '{ gsub(/foo/, "bar" ) } ; { print $0 }' file > tmp.txt && mv -v tmp.txt file``` ?

Comment: To my surprise, as of April 2019, still at gawk 4.0.2. Don't let anyone tell you such and such version will be available.

Comment: Litte shorter `awk '{print $0}' file | sponge file` using `sponge` from `moreutils`.

Comment: Note that `mv tmp file` is not in general sufficient - the file perms may have changed and must be fixed. `-i inplace` doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 28):

just a little hack that works

```
echo "$(awk '{awk code}' file)" > file
```

Comment: Works like a charm! But is it possible to save awk command into variable and just use it in your nifty trick?

Comment: The `-i inplace` method breaks hardlinks, this hack follows hardlinks♥♥

Answer (score 18):

An alternative is to use `sponge`:

```
awk '{print $0}' your_file | sponge your_file
```

Where you replace `'{print $0}'` by your awk script and `your_file` by the name of the file you want to edit in place.

`sponge` absorbs entirely the input before saving it to the file.

Comment: How standard/portable is sponge?

Comment: `sponge` is part of `moreutils`. So it won't be present by default in most systems. But looks like at least `sponge` itself is portable enough and can be run almost everywhere.

Comment: The downside of this solution compared to `tee`-based is that `sponge` will read everything to RAM before writing down, hence it will freeze on large files.

Answer (score 17):

[@sudo_O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066031/iiseymour) has the right [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529730/).

This can't work:

```
someprocess < file > file
```

The shell performs the redirections *before* handing control over to someprocess ([redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)). The `>` redirection will truncate the file to zero size ([redirecting output](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Output)). Therefore, by the time someprocess gets launched and wants to read from the file, there is no data for it to read.

Answer (score 6):

following won't work

```
echo $(awk '{awk code}' file) > file
```

this should work

```
echo "$(awk '{awk code}' file)" > file
```

Comment: `echo` with `-n` option to avoid trailing newline.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want an awk-only solution without creating a temporary file and usable with version!=(gawk 4.1.0):

```
awk '{a[b++]=$0} END {for(c=0;c<=b;c++)print a[c]>ARGV[1]}' file
```

Comment: But does this buffer the entire file to memory? Consider a 20GB file.