# Shell scripting Sed option

Tags: sed

I need a help in the shell scripting processing the file. The script should read each file in the path and replace the string in each row.

It should read each line and replace the 7th column with XXXX mentioned in the sample output. Any help in appreciated.

Input file data

```
"2013-04-30"|"X"|"0000628"|"15000231"|"1999-12-05"|"ST"|"2455525445552000"|"1111-11-11"|75.00|"XXE11111"|"224425"
"2013-04-30"|"Y"|"0000928"|"95000232"|"1999-12-05"|"VT"|"2455525445552000"|"1111-11-11"|95.00|"VVE11111"|"224425"
```

output file

```
"2013-04-30"|"X"|"0000628"|"15000231"|"1999-12-05"|"ST"|"24555XXXXXXXXXX"|"1111-11-11"|75.00|"XXE11111"|"224425"
"2013-04-30"|"Y"|"0000928"|"95000232"|"1999-12-05"|"VT"|"24555XXXXXXXXXX"|"1111-11-11"|95.00|"VVE11111"|"224425"
```

Script I used to run but it is not editing the input file

```
FILES=/home/auto/*.txt
for f in $FILES
do
echo "Processing $f file..."
cat $f | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"; OFS="|"} {$7=substr($7, 1, 6)"XXXXXXXXXX\"";print}'
done
```

but I can't edit the exiting file in the directory. I need to use the `sed -i` option but it's not working.

---

I tried using the script in below server but I am getting the following error.

```
SunOS 5.10      Generic January 2005
```

```
echo "hello"

FILES=/export/home/*.txt
for f in $FILES
do
echo "Processing $f file..."
sed -i -r 's/"([^"]{6})[^"]*"/"\1XXXXXXXXXX"/6' "$f"
done
```

I get

```
sed: illegal option -- i
```

Comment: With Solaris `sed`, you will have to redirect the output to a temporary file and then copy or move the temporary file over the original.  You may or may not find that it supports the `-r` option; IIRC, it does not.  In that case, you will need to use `\(...\)` for grouping and `\{n,m\}` for counting groups.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU sed with `-i` optoin

```
sed -i -r 's/"([^"]{5})[^"]*"/"\1XXXXXXXXXX"/5' file


"2013-04-30"|"X"|"0000628"|"15000231"|"1999-12-05"|"ST"|"24555XXXXXXXXXX"|"1111-11-11"|75.00|"XXE11111"|"224425"
"2013-04-30"|"Y"|"0000928"|"95000232"|"1999-12-05"|"VT"|"24555XXXXXXXXXX"|"1111-11-11"|95.00|"VVE11111"|"224425"
```

Comment: Nicely done; you're missing two `X` chars, though. OSX users: use `sed -i '' -E` instead of `sed -i -r`.

Comment: Nice finding,Thanks, I updated. But I have no OSX system to check with your suggestion in OSX sed. :-(

Comment: Thanks; no worries re OSX - it's not clear what platform the OP uses; I sometimes add the OSX info so that OSX users can benefit from the answers too - often it's just a minor thing, such as different option names.

Comment: If i need to change the sed option to change first 6 digit instead of 5 digit what is the sed command .Pls let me know

Comment: change from `{5}` to `{6}`, and adjust the number of `X`,

Answer (score 1):

if your awk is gnu awk 4.1.0, there is `in-place` option, read man/info page.
otherwise, you could do:

```
awk '..code..' inputfile > tmpfile && mv tmpfile inputfile
```

note, the `cat` is not necessary, could (should) be removed.

Comment: The `gawk 4.1+`  pointer is helpful, but (a) its name is `inplace` and (b) it's an *extension*, not an option; neither `man` nor `info` contain information about it; a demonstration can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16529730/45375 and more info in the online manual at http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace.

Comment: @mklement0 yes, it is `inplace` and there is explanation and examples in my gawk info page. info gawk, and search `inplace`, you will find

Comment: Interesting; looks like some distros (e.g., Ubuntu) simply show you the contents of the `man` page when you do `info gawk` - where the `inplace` info is _not_ present.

Answer (score 1):

A little ugly but you can try something like this with `sed`

```
sed -i 's/\(\([^|]*|\)\{6\}\)\(.\{6\}\).\{11\}\(.*\)/\1\3XXXXXXXXXXX\4/' file
```

So with your existing script, it will be -

```
FILES=/home/auto/*.txt
for f in $FILES
do
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    sed -i 's/\(\([^|]*|\)\{6\}\)\(.\{6\}\).\{11\}\(.*\)/\1\3XXXXXXXXXXX\4/' "$f"
done
```

Comment: Jay-Nice i can see the result but can you explain so if i need to modify first 7 digit instead of 5 digit i can do it later .what is 6 , 6 ,11,1,3XXX etc

Comment: The numbers represent the exact match you want to preserve. I am guessing you mean to say preserve first 7 digits instead of 5 then change the second `\{6\}` to `\{8\}` and reduce 3 X in replacement.