# Bash remove duplicate words from file (regex: sed,awk)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have read other questions that were very similar to mine. However, when I tried the suggested codes, it did not work

So I have a file with the following content

`COMP 232:MATH. FOR COMPUTER SCIENCE:3 credits
summer:Lect AA:-T-J--- (10:45-13:15):SGW H-521:KRATOCHVIL, VACLAV
   Tut AE:-T-J--- (13:45-15:25):SGW H-521
fall:Lect Q:-T-J--- (13:15-14:30):SGW H-820:GRAHNE, GOSTA
   Tut QA:-T----- (16:15-17:55):SGW H-607
   Tut QB:---J--- (14:45-16:25):SGW H-619
fall:Lect R:-T-J--- (13:15-14:30):SGW H-937:NARAYANAN, LATA
   Tut RA:-T----- (16:15-17:55):SGW H-1070
   Tut RB:-T----- (16:15-17:55):SGW GN-M100
fall:Lect DD:--W---- (17:45-20:15):SGW FG-C070:DOEDEL, EUSEBIUS
   Tut DA:--W---- (20:30-22:10):SGW H-429
   Tut DB:--W---- (20:30-22:10):SGW H-619
winter:Lect S:-T-J--- (13:15-14:30):SGW H-561:BERGLER, SABINE
   Tut SA:-T----- (14:45-16:25):SGW H-920
winter:Lect NN:---J--- (17:45-20:15):SGW H-520:GRAHNE, GOSTA
   Tut NA:---J--- (20:30-22:10):SGW H-520
   Tut NB:-T----- (20:30-22:10):SGW H-607`

and I would like my output to be this

`COMP 232:MATH. FOR COMPUTER SCIENCE:3 credits
summer:Lect AA:-T-J--- (10:45-13:15):SGW H-521:KRATOCHVIL, VACLAV
   Tut AE:-T-J--- (13:45-15:25):SGW H-521
fall:Lect Q:-T-J--- (13:15-14:30):SGW H-820:GRAHNE, GOSTA
   Tut QA:-T----- (16:15-17:55):SGW H-607
   Tut QB:---J--- (14:45-16:25):SGW H-619
   Lect R:-T-J--- (13:15-14:30):SGW H-937:NARAYANAN, LATA
   Tut RA:-T----- (16:15-17:55):SGW H-1070
   Tut RB:-T----- (16:15-17:55):SGW GN-M100
   Lect DD:--W---- (17:45-20:15):SGW FG-C070:DOEDEL, EUSEBIUS
   Tut DA:--W---- (20:30-22:10):SGW H-429
   Tut DB:--W---- (20:30-22:10):SGW H-619
winter:Lect S:-T-J--- (13:15-14:30):SGW H-561:BERGLER, SABINE
   Tut SA:-T----- (14:45-16:25):SGW H-920
   Lect NN:---J--- (17:45-20:15):SGW H-520:GRAHNE, GOSTA
   Tut NA:---J--- (20:30-22:10):SGW H-520
   Tut NB:-T----- (20:30-22:10):SGW H-607`

I have tried the following codes, but none produced my desired output

```sh
sed -e 's/\b\([a-z]\+\)[ ,\n]\1/\1/g' temp.txt
```

```sh
sort -u temp.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks lengthy a bit, but works fine:

```
prev="dummy"
while read line
do
   tag=$(echo $line | grep -Eo "^[a-zA-Z]+:")
   if [ "$tag" == "$prev" ]
   then
     echo "  ${line#$tag}"
   else
     if [ "$tag" != "" ] 
     then
        prev="$tag"
     else
        echo -n "  "
   fi
   echo "$line"
fi
done < /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk 4.1

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
@include "join"
{
  split($0, foo, ":")
  if (seen[foo[1]]++)
    $0 = "   " join(foo, 2, length(foo), ":")
}
1
```

[awk save modifications in place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/#16529730)

Comment: I'm putting this in my `test.sh` bash code but the final closing bracket `}` is highlighted **red**. And also instead of `foo` I put my filename?