# Process on the same file without temp (intermediate) file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I am doing some text process on a file using awk. For instance removing the trailing whitespace.

```
awk '{gsub(/ +$/, "")} {print $0}' filename
```

This works fine. But when I redirect the output to the original file. It becomes an empty file.

```
temp$ awk '{gsub(/ +$/, "")} {print $0}' abc > abc
temp$ cat abc
temp$
```

So I tried another way. Use cat and pipe rather than as a input parameter of awk.

```
temp$ cat abc | awk '{gsub(/ +$/, "")} {print $0}' abc > abc
temp$ cat abc
temp$
```

Still doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve the same goal without involving an intermediate file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace

Comment: I'd like to get at the root of the question first: What about having an intermediate file is a problem for you? Is it just the hassle of creating/copying/deleting it? Or something else?

Comment: No certain reason, just want to keep it clean.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `sed -i` and `sed` will handle it for you

example:

```
sed -i 's/[ \t]*$//g' file
```

Comment: Thanks. And I saw this kind of answer by using sed before. But the point is, I am not just doing this kind of operation. What if I do some more complicated process which sed cannot do and I still don't want to use an intermediate file?

Comment: you can write small function wich will do it for you and use it whenever it's needed. Otherwise it's impossible without intermediate file. For more comlicated stuff you can use perl -i as well.

Comment: Note that `sed -i ...` is still using a temporary file - it just hides the details from you. It doesn't really edit in-place - that's difficult, if not impossible, to do in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with use of `> abc` is that shell processes redirection first and initializes the file `abc` to 0 byte **before it runs your actual command**. So in other words your awk command is run on an empty 0 byte file.

Here is a trick you can use not just for this command but for any other command as well.

```
f='abc'
awk '{sub(/ +$/, "")} 1' "$f" | awk -c f="$f" -v RS=$'\g' 'END{printf $0 > f}'
```

`$'\g'` is just a randomly selected improbable record separator that will **never exist** in any file cause whole file to be read in one line. Trick is to read whole file in one record and write in the output only in `END` section. **This will work with big size files also.**

---

**Earlier Solution:**
You can make use of `tee`:

```
awk '{gsub(/ +$/, "")} {print $0}' abc | tee abc
```

If you want to discard output on stdout use:

```
awk '{gsub(/ +$/, "")} {print $0}' abc | tee abc > /dev/null
```

Comment: I doubt this would work for very large files. You can use sponge perhaps.

Comment: the reason it seems to work is because all your test file can be buffered. If you have a large file it cannot be buffered before writting by tee. Test using these commands: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2b7241d6940d21690c3e

Comment: sorry, slight mistake in the verification. check this out: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2c37cfdd42507caa4b44

Comment: Sorry -1. your solution is broken and should not be used in production. you might corrupt your data.

Comment: If I understand correctly the whole file is loaded into memory? This might still be a problem with large files. Writing the data as it is processed seems like the best option to me. Trying to avoid the temporary file with a more complex and less efficient solution sounds like a bad idea. "you can't make an omelette without breaking eggs".

Comment: In modern systems it shouldn't be a problem at all to process big files. How big can the input file be that is for OP to check. In any case this solution is for the question that says **Process on the same file without temp (intermediate) file**.

Answer (score 1):

There is several possible solutions. But please make sur you test with a large file, on my machine a file of less than ~100Ko will work with this: `cat abc | tee abc > /dev/null` but the problem occur when the pipe buffer is full and is then sent to the next process. When tee receive the first chunk of information it writes to the file then the cat process cannot read anymore from that file, this result in corrupting your data.

Use gawk 4.1+ you have the option inplace (-i) like sed does.
see this post: 
[awk save modifications in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace)

If you cant use gawk 4.1 you can still convert to a sed inplace expression like others are suggesting.

Otherwise to keep it as a one liner you can use sponge (part of moreutils) to redirect to de same file:

```
$ yes testing | head -n10000000 > /tmp/test
$ du /tmp/test
77M     /tmp/test
$ cat /tmp/test | sponge /tmp/test
$ du /tmp/test
77M     /tmp/test
```

If installing `moreutils` to use sponge is not possible for you I suggest a simple temp file then moving the file:

```
$ tmp=$(mktemp)
$ echo $tmp
/tmp/tmp.Tl0v8HmdaA
$  awk '{gsub(/ +$/, "")} {print $0}' abc > $tmp
$ mv $tmp abc
```

Answer (score 1):

use `sponge` from [moreutils tools](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)

> ```
> Probably the most general purpose tool in moreutils so far is sponge(1), 
> which lets you do things like this:
> ```
>
> `% sed "s/root/toor/" /etc/passwd | grep -v joey | sponge /etc/passwd`

***e.g:***

```
/tmp$ cat -E abc 
aaaaa    $
/tmp$ awk '{gsub(/ +$/, "")} {print $0}' abc | sponge abc 
/tmp$ cat -E abc 
aaaaa$
```