# bash, adding string after a line

Tags: bash, loops, awk, sed

I'm trying to put together a bash script that will search a bunch of files and if it finds a particular string in a file, it will add a new line on the line after that string and then move on to the next file.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Creating variables"
SEARCHDIR=testfile
LINENUM=1
find $SEARCHDIR* -type f -name *.xml | while read i; do
echo "Checking $i"

  ISBE=`cat $i | grep STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR`
   if [[ $ISBE =~ "STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR" ]] ; then
     echo "found $i"
     cat $i | while read LINE; do
      ((LINENUM=LINENUM+1))
      if [[ $LINE == "<STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR>" ]] ; then
        echo "editing $i"
        awk -v "n=$LINENUM" -v "s=new line to insert" '(NR==n) { print s } 1' $i 
      fi
  done
  fi
LINENUM=1
done
```

the bit I'm having trouble with is

```
awk -v "n=$LINENUM" -v "s=new line to insert" '(NR==n) { print s } 1' $i
```

if I just use $i at the end, it will output the content to the screen, if I use `$i > $i` then it will just erase the file and if I use `$i >> $i` it will get stuck in a loop until the disk fills up.

any suggestions?

Comment: Then just redirect to a temp file and then move it to your original one. Also, I guess your code could be reduced a lot using the right tools. A `find` and `awk` should be more or less enough, whereas you use many different things.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately awk dosen't have an in-place replacement option, similar to sed's `-i`, so you can create a temp file and then remove it:

```
awk '{commands}' file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
```

or if you have [GNU awk 4.1.0 or newer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529730/), the `-i inplace` is added, so you can do:

```
awk -i inplace '{commands}' file
```

to modify the original

Answer (score 1):

If you can, maybe use a temporary file?

```
~$ awk ... $i > tmpfile
~$ mv tmpfile $i
```

Or simply `awk  ... $i > tmpfile && mv tmpfile $i`

Note that, you can use [`mktemp`](http://man.cx/mktemp) to create this temporary file.

Otherwise, with sed you can insert a line right after a match:

```
~$ cat f
auie
nrst
abcd
efgh
1234

~$ sed '/abcd/{a\
new_line
}' f
auie
nrst
abcd
new_line
efgh
1234
```

The command search if the line matches `/abcd/`, if so, it will append (`a\`) the line `new_line`.

And since `sed` as the `-i` to replace inline, you can do:

```
if [[ $ISBE =~ "STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR" ]] ; then
     echo "found $i"
     echo "editing $i"
     sed -i "/STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR/{a
\new line to insert
}" $i 
fi
```

Comment: it is best to use `awk '...' file > tmp && mv tmp file`, like user00...0001 did. The `&&` trick prevents overwriting `file` with some bad output in case `awk` failed.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the sed option. I found I also had a problem with my loop but the sed method allowed me to uncover it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#cat $i | while read LINE; do
#  ((LINENUM=LINENUM+1))
#  if [[ $LINE == "<STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR>" ]] ; then
#    echo "editing $i"
#    awk -v "n=$LINENUM" -v "s=new line to insert" '(NR==n) { print s } 1' $i 
#  fi
# done

# replaced by
sed -i 's/STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR/&\n/g' ${i}
```

or use awk in place of sed

also

```
# ISBE=`cat $i | grep STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR`
# if [[ $ISBE =~ "STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR" ]] ; then
#by
if [ $( grep -c 'STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR' ${i} ) -gt 0 ]; then
# if file are huge, if not directly used sed on it, it will be faster (but no echo about finding the file)
```