# AWK - replace with constant character in a specified number of random lines

Tags: bash, awk

I'm tasked with imputing masked genotypes, and I have to mask (hide) 2% of genotypes.

The file I do this in looks like this (genotype.dat):

```
M rs4911642
M rs9604821
M rs9605903
M rs5746647
M rs5747968
M rs5747999
M rs2070501
M rs11089263
M rs2096537
```

and to mask it, I simply change M to S2.

Yet, I have to do this for 110 (2%) of 5505 lines, so my strategy of using a random number generator (generate 110 numbers between 1 and 5505 and then manually changing the corresponding line number's M to S2 took almost an hour... (I know, not terribly sophisticated).

I thought about saving the numbers in a separate file (maskedlines.txt) and then telling awk to replace the first character in that line number with S2, but I could not find any adjustable example of to do this.

Anyway, any suggestions of how to tackle this will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next;} a[FNR]{$1="S2"} 1' maskedlines.txt genotype.dat
```

#### How it works

In sum, we first read in `maskedlines.txt` into an associative array `a`.  This file is assumed to have one number per line and `a` of that number is set to one.  We then read in `genotype.dat`.  If `a` for that line number is one, we change the first field to `S2` to mask it.  The line, whether changed or not, is then printed.

In detail:

- `NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next;}`

  In awk, `FNR` is the number of records (lines) read so far from the current file and `NR` is the total number of lines read so far.  So, when `NR==FNR`, we are reading the first file (maskedlines.txt).  This file contains the line number of lines in genotype.dat that are to be masked.  For each of these line numbers, we set `a` to 1.  We then skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `a[FNR]{$1="S2"}`

  If we get here, we are working on the second file: genotype.dat.  For each line in this file, we check to see if its line number, `FNR`, was mentioned in `maskedlines.txt`.  If it was, we set the first field to `S2` to mask this line.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand to print the current line.

Comment: that worked perfectly; many thanks. Apparently I need to generate a new file by adding > maskedgenotype.dat and then mv genotype.dat but that is fine. Also thanks for a very useful explanation.

Comment: @user3100623 Glad it worked.  And, yes, create `maskedgenotype.dat` and then `mv`.  If you have a very recent version of GNU awk (4.1.0 or later), then there is a built-in shortcut for this: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16529730/3030305

Answer (score 1):

Here's one simple way, if you have `shuf` (it's in Gnu coreutils, so if you have Linux, you almost certainly have it):

```
sed "$(printf '%ds/M/S2/;' $(shuf -n110 -i1-5505 | sort -n))" \
    genotype.dat > genotype.masked
```

A more sophisticated version wouldn't depend on knowing that you want 110 of 5505 lines masked; you can easily extract the line count with `lines=$(wc -l < genotype.dat)`, and from there you can compute the percentage.

`shuf` is used to produce a random sample of lines, usually from a file; the `-i1-5505` option means to use the integers from 1 to 5505 instead, and `-n110` means to produce a random sample of 110 (without repetition). I sorted that for efficiency before using `printf` to create a `sed` edit script.

Comment: I see, so this would save me the step of generating random numbers externally... can I ask what does "%ds" stand for? s is substitute I'm guessing, but the d?

Comment: @IsidorLipsch It's a printf format. %d is an integer, and s is a literal s (as in the sed `s` command). If you prefer an external list, you can use that instead of `shuf`, but `shuf` is really handy for sampling.