# Test if pattern in file exists, evaluate if

Tags: bash, awk

I want to test if a pattern exists in a file.

1. If the pattern exists (In a file among a list), do a replacement and update the corresponded file.
2. If the pattern doesn't exists, do nothing.

So far I have done:

```
    if [ -f $((`awk '/Pattern1/' $FILE`))];then
        sed 's/Pattern1/\nWORD/g' $FILE > a
        mv a $FILE
    fi
```

But, when I test it, I get the following error:

```
syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator
```

And I don't want to evaluate the numeric part, just if the pttern~string is there or not.

**Input of file 1**

```
Rho =  1.1955904623E+02     Rho at Nucleus =  1.1955904594E+02
```

**Input of file2**

```
Rho =  1.1955904623E+02
```

Comment: If you are using awk to look for the pattern why not use awk to do the entire job?  Seems strange to switch to sed.

Comment: What would you recommend me instead of my procedure?

Comment: you miss one space character before ]; bash is brutal!

Comment: one idea, you can use wildcards for filenames, like *.txt to catch all txt files in folder, then no need for using bash, only sed or awk will be enough

Comment: @josifoski good idea and yes, you were right, the but was only a space. Thank you for helping out and have a good day : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply go ahead with the substitution, if the pattern exist something will be changed, if not, nothing will be done to the file.

```
awk '{sub(/Pattern1/, "\nWORD"); print}' $FILE > tmp && mv tmp $FILE
```

check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/1254880).