# awk delete line if number of rows = some number

Tags: shell, unix, awk

**This is my *awk* code:**

```
awk -F"," 'NF!= 8' myfile.csv
```

How can I delete only lines that have 8 fields.

Comment: What's the difference in your mind between `delete lines with 8 fields` and `print lines that do not have 8 fields`? You're not seriously asking how to change `!=` to `==` are you?

Comment: If you change `!=` to `==`, your code will print the lines that have 8 fields.  Using `=` instead of `==` won't do what you want.  However, I'm really not clear what you're asking...

Comment: I accidentally approved an edit to my question that was wrong. I just want to delete lines with fields ==8.

Comment: And the code in the updated question (`awk 'NF!=8'`) prints only those lines that do not have 8 fields, effectively deleting those that do have 8 fields.  What's the problem?  Why are you asking a question when your code contains the answer?

Comment: Is the question how to use that to modify the original file?

Comment: If @EtanReisner is correct then you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/16529730/1066031

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output. I wonder if the problem you're having is that you're telling awk to use `,` as the Field Separator but your input file isn't separated by commas. I know the suffix is `.csv` but we see that with fields separate by tabs, semi-colons, pipe symbols, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go (this prints lines with 8 fields as originally asked)

```
awk -F, 'NF==8' myfile.csv
```

The question changed, you want to remove the lines with 8 fields.  One way to do this

```
awk -F, 'NF!=8' myfile.csv > temp && mv temp mvfile.csv
```

NB. updated as per comments

Comment: This prints the lines that have 8 fields. I want to use awk to delete those lines with 8 fields. (Sorry someone edited my question and it turned out wrong.)