# awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $2,$3,$5;}' loop possibility using a one-liner?

Tags: awk

```
'awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $2,$3,$5;}' <file>'
```

Using this command, is it possible to have it go through multiple files, ie file* at the end and if not how can i do this?

i have

```
file.01
file.02 
through file.20
```

All of the files can be replaced directly. An out file is not needed although i still need the split files to exist in their current chunks of 250mb

Comment: what OS (output of `uname -rvosi` please), and what version of awk, i.e.`awk --version`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - awk takes any number of files as arguments, and processes them in sequence.  See `man awk`:

```
SYNOPSIS
       awk [ -F fs ] [ -v var=value ] [ 'prog' | -f progfile ] [ file ...  ]
```

and, in fact, you can access the name of the file current filename with the variable `FILENAME`.

You can do this with:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $2,$3,$5;}' file*
```

for all files that start with the text `file`.

Comment: I am new to using this command and scripting in general so how could i accomplish this?

Comment: @JonathonVasile  `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $2,$3,$5;}' file.01 file.02` etc. or `cat file.* | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $2,$3,$5;}'`

Comment: @jayant when i run 'cat $(date +"%d-%m-%Y").WE.* | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $2,$3,$5;}' ' it will only scroll on screen and not overwrite the file

Comment: @JonathonVasile yes that's because awk doesn't modify the file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace