# looping multiple arithmetic processes over multiple files in linux using sed or awk

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, sed

I have about 1000 files that contain xyz Cartesian coordinates of chemical structures, a sample is provided below

```
Re                -0.87242200         -0.87371100        0.24194200   
Re                -1.38612300          1.83520600        0.44292100
Re                 1.78955700         -0.15746900        0.71425500
```

What I'd like to do, preferably through a 'for' loop, is to add an extra line after the second encounter of Re, in that line add a symbol 'H' at the first position of the line then introduce xyz coordinates in the form 1.5+X  1.5+Y 1.5+Z, where X Y and Z are the coordinates of the the second Re. These xyz coordinates should be in position 20, 40 and 60 in the new line (for X, Y and Z respectively).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  What you need to do seems nice and straight forward in `awk`.  What did you try and how did it fail to do what you want?  On SO, we will help you fix your attempt to solve a problem; we won't go out of our way to simply write the code for you.

Comment: In your example file, the 3rd column starts at 58.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Thanks. I'm still learning and not fully experienced with bash yet. I've already succeeded, using sed, to append a new line starting with 'H' after the second occurrence of Re. But I'm stuck at the next step, don't know yet how to extract the xyz values, I guess $2, $3, and $4 of Re, add the constant to the values and insert them as $2, $3 and $4 in the H line.

Comment: @ Micha Wiedenmann. Thanks for pointing that out. The 20, 40 and 60 positions are not strict, I just put it like that for simplicity. The exact space is not very important, the columns just have to be within a couple of spaces of each other.

Comment: When the task involves floating point arithmetic, neither `sed` nor Bash is the appropriate tool (Bash only supports integer arithmetic; Korn shell supports floating point).  Awk is the next step up; you could use Perl or Python instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a task for Awk (or Perl or Python).  It isn't suitable for Sed because it can't do arithmetic; it isn't really suitable for Bash because it only does integer arithmetic.  It could be done in Korn shell because it supports floating-point arithmetic, but Awk is probably the best tool for the task.

In the sample data, all the lines begin `Re`.  For such data, this is sufficient:

```
awk '/^Re / { print
              if (++count == 2)
                  printf("%-18s %-19s %-19% %s\n", "H", $2+1.5, $3+1.5, $4+1.5) }'
```

If there are other symbols at the start of a line that need to be printed, then you need:

```
awk '/^Re / { print
              if (++count == 2)
                  printf("%-18s %-19s %-19% %s\n", "H", $2+1.5, $3+1.5, $4+1.5)
              next }
            { print }'
```

The next skips the trailing `{ print }` which processes any other lines. That `{ print }` could be abbreviated to `1` or any other non-zero (true) value which triggers the default action, namely `print`.  With the addition of a couple of semicolons, either script could be squished onto a single line, but I think the clarity of multiple lines is better.

```
awk '/^Re / { print; if (++count == 2) printf("%-18s %-19s %-19% %s\n", "H", $2+1.5, $3+1.5, $4+1.5); next } { print }'
```

If you need to control the number of decimal places printed, you can use `%-19.8f` or `%+-19.8f` instead of the `%-19s` and `%s` conversion specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following `awk` script:

```
BEGIN      { count = 0 }
/^\<Re\>/  { x=$2; y=$3; z=$4;
             count++;
             print;
           }
count == 2 { printf "%-18s %-19s %-17s %s\n", "H", 1.5+x, 1.5+y, 1.5+z }
```

you can run it on multiple files with:

```
for f in file*.txt; do
  gawk -i inplace -f add-H.awk -- "$f"
done
```

Note that this requires a recent version of GNU awk, which supports inplace modification (see [awk save modifications in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace)).

Comment: You're a life saver!. Because of your help I can still catch my allocation time on the University's server to run calculations, otherwise I'd have to wait for another week. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's a long way of writing `awk '/^Re / { print; if (++count == 2) printf("%-18s %-19s %-19% %s\n", "H", $2+1.5, $3+1.5, $4+1.5) }'`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler. Nicer and simpler, Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Please either update my answer or post a new answer, so I can delete mine.