# Adding Maven dependency with command line

Tags: java, maven, command-line, dependencies, maven-3

I've just installed Maven 3 - I'm new to Java and I want to learn how Maven works. For now, I know that I can add a dependency by editing POM file in the maven project, but I wonder if there is a 'clean' way to do it with command line.
Running Windows 8.1, Java 8, Maven 3.

Comment: Also, is there any way to use some kind of external repository like mvnrepository.com?

Comment: Note that adding a jar to your local m2 repo does not mean that the pom will use it

Comment: What does "m2" mean? Maven 2?

Comment: yes. In your home folder you will find it. In *nix OS it's hidden (.m2) in Windows, I don't know.

Comment: You can't, that would be too simple. You need to manually find the latest version, edit an XML file, find the right place to put it and wrap everything in 3 different XML tags and close those tags because everything in Java has to take extra time so you can charge more money for all those hours your Java programmers work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the POM directly is probably a better way, but yes you can do that:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId="group-id" \
-DartifactId="artifact-id" -Dversion="version" -Dpackaging="packaging"
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Seems to work fine with downloaded *.jar files. Is there a way to use external repositories? (see comment to the thread)

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html - this might be of use

Comment: This adds a jar to your local .m2 repo. But if the pow does not include it, it will ignore it

Comment: The OP asks for a way to add a dependency in a project via CLI instead of manually editing POM; while your answer is about installing a JAR in the local Maven repository. Two different things.

Comment: I dont know why this is the best answer. The question is about editing pom using command line...

Answer (score 6):

I'm not very sure if there's a built-in maven feature or plugin to do so, but I don't think so. You could achieve it by a small script using `sed` or something similar. I've used the following in a bash script:

```sh
get_foo_dep() {
  cat <<EOF
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <version>${DEP_VERSION}</version>
    </dependency>
EOF
}

DEP_VERSION="1.0.0"  # just example, you can set it from somewhere
POM_FILE="pom.xml"   # just example, the path to pom

foo_dep=$(get_foo_dep)
foo_dep=${foo_dep//$'\n'/\\$'\n'}   # escape \n with \\n for sed to work
sed -i "s|<dependencies>|<dependencies>\n${foo_dep}|" "$POM_FILE"  # CARE!! it makes in-place substitution
```

You can also have a look at this other question, where `awk` is recommended:

[Is it possible to use sed to replace dependencies's version in a pom file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957616/is-it-possible-to-use-sed-to-replace-dependenciess-version-in-a-pom-file)