# Remove duplicate lines and overwrite file in same command

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to remove duplicate lines from a file and update the file. For some reason I have to write it to a new file and replace it. Is this the only way?

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' .gitignore > .gitignore

awk '!seen[$0]++' .gitignore > .gitignore_new && mv .gitignore_new .gitignore
```

Comment: It's the only **smart** way. Deleting in place is possible, but it requires the file to be opened without truncation. Then when it is written, it has to be truncated to the new size. It's a hassle even if we don't consider cases when the operation is interrupted, leaving a half-baked file.

Answer (score 13):

Redirecting to the same output file as input file like:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' .gitignore > .gitignore
```

will end with an empty file. This is because using the `>` operator, the shell will open and truncate the file *before* the command get's executed. Meaning **you'll lose all your data.**

With newer versions of GNU awk you can use the `-i inplace` option to edit the file *in place*:

```
awk -i inplace '!seen[$0]++' .gitignore
```

If you don't have a recent version of GNU awk, you'll need to create a temporary file:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' .gitignore > .gitignore.tmp
mv .gitignore.tmp .gitignore
```

Another alternative is to use the `sponge` program from [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' .gitignore | sponge .gitignore
```

`sponge` will soak all stdinput and open the output file after that. This effectively keeps the input file intact before writing to it.

Comment: Does not work. `gawk: fatal: can't open source file \`!seen[$0]++' for reading (No such file or directory)`.

Comment: That's with `gawk` on the `master` branch, as of the Jun 6, 2016 commit `4f758771937fcbd59b1fd2db017c4995513c3988` by Robbins.

Comment: @Kaz As I said, `-i` is a relatively new gawk feature. Looks like your `gawk` doesn't support it.

Comment: `-i` is for including files; it requires an argument.

Comment: Yes it requires an argument, you are right. Changed that. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16531920/171318 .. Actually in place editing in awk is realized using an include.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas, I believe the problem is that you are reading from it and writing to it on the same command.  This is why you must put to a temporary file first.

The > does overwrite, so you are using the correct redirect operator

> - Redirect output from a command to a file on disk. Note: if the file already exist, it will be erased and overwritten without warning, so
>     be careful.
>
> Example: ps -ax >processes.txt Use the ps command to get a list of
>   processes running on the system, and store the output in a file named
>   processes.txt

Answer (score -2):

Yes, because if you don't do that shell will create file descriptor and truncate .gitignore even before awk process started.