# Print paragraph after matching pattern

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I would like to print the lines between two empty lines only after a match is made. My data looks like this:

```
List A
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3

Item 4
Item 5

List B
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

Thus, I'm trying to get a sed or awk or grep command to match List A and get the output of

```
Item 4
Item 5
```

So far, I have tried doing:

```
sed '/^$/,/^$/!d'
```

and

```
sed '/list\sA.*^$/,/^$/!d'
```

In this case, I'm trying to print the range and define the first pattern as the string and everything included until the empty line.

I have also tried other code with:

```
awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n'
```

But, this only gives me the paragraph that contains the pattern, I'm trying to get the paragraph after that.

Finally, I think it is something using `sed -n` and uses the { } with labels but I'm just not advanced enough to put it all together. Would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: so the match you are doing is a paragraph containing "A"?

Comment: Not exactly, I would like to match "List A" and print the paragraph after that which would be: Item 4 Item 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you match a pattern, get the next record with [`getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html):

```
$ awk -v RS='' '/List A/ {getline; print}' file
Item 4
Item 5
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I had to add a few things to make sure formatting was good but that is correct code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Quick follow up on this one. If I wanted to remove those two lines from the file, is there an easy way to do that using a similar awk command?

Comment: @DomainsFeatured you want to check [awk modifications in place](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16529730/1983854).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `awk` here as shown in fedorqui's answer. However, the following `sed` command would work as well:

```
sed -n '/List A/{:a;n;/^$/!ba;:b;n;/^$/!{p;bb}}' file
```

Explanation:

```
/List A/ { 
    :a          # Label "a"
    n           # Get new line from input
    /^$/! ba    # If this line is not empty jump back to :a
    :b          # Label "b"
    n           # Get new line from input
    /^$/! {     # If this line is not empty:
        p       #   Print the line
        bb      #   Jump back to :b  
    }
}
```

The option `-n` suppresses printing of lines unless `p` is used.