# Update tab-delimited file in-place with gawk

Tags: gawk

I am trying to add field headers to a file in-place using `gawk`.  The input `file` is tab delimited so I added that to the command. If I substitute `gawk -i inplace` with just `awk` the command runs but the `file` is not updated. I know `awk` doesn't have an in-place edit like `sed`, but can `gawk` be used or is there a better way?

```
gawk -i inplace '
BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"
}
NR == 1 {
$1= "Chr"
$2= "Start"
$3= "End"
$4= "Gene"
}
1' file
```

**file (input file to update)**

```
chr7    121738788   121738930   AASS
chr7    121738788   121738930   AASS
chr7    121738788   121738930   AASS
```

**desired output**

```
Chr     Start       End         Gene
chr7    121738788   121738930   AASS
chr7    121738788   121738930   AASS
chr7    121738788   121738930   AASS
```

I was using the SO Q&A [`awk` save modifications in place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace) as a guide but was not able to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {print  "Chr\tStart\tEnd\tGene"}1' file > newFile && mv newFile file
```

Output

```
Chr     Start   End     Gene
chr7    121738788   121738930   AASS
chr7    121738788   121738930   AASS
chr7    121738788   121738930   AASS
```

As it seems you're mostly interested in adding a header line, just print that before anything happens (via the `BEGIN` block). The `1` is a "true" statement, so all lines of input are printed (by default). You could replace it with the long hand `{print $0}` if you want code that non awk-gurus will understand.

Even using a `-i inplace` option, the program is doing the same as `awk 'code' file > newFile && mv newFile file` behind the scenes, so there is no "savings" in processing to adding a header to a file. The file has to be rewritten in either case.

IHTH

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanations, I really appreciate them :)

Answer (score 1):

It'd be more efficient to just do:

```
cat - file <<<$'Chr\tStart\tEnd\tGene' > newfile && mv newfile file
```

with no awk involvement at all.