# How to substring version value using sed?

Tags: bash, sed, cut

Input strings are as follows.

```
6.5.1.2.3
6.10.3.9.6
7.2.0.0.0
10.11.12.13.4
```

And I want to extract first two digit and replace period character to underscore using sed

```
6_5
6_10
7_2
10_11
```

When I used this:

```
sed 's/\./_/g' | cut -c 1-3
```

6_10, 10_11 result was not correct.

Is there any work around here?

Answer (score 4):

`awk` is also useful for such things. If you set the output field separator `OFS`:

```
$ awk -F"." -v OFS="_" '{print $1, $2}' file
6_5
6_10
7_2
10_11
```

But if you really need `sed` use back references (here with extended regular expressions — note that the option is sometimes `-E` and sometimes only basic regular expressions are supported by `sed`):

```
$ sed -r 's/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+).*/\1_\2/' file
6_5
6_10
7_2
10_11
```

If you want to perform in-place replacing, you can either say `awk/sed '...' file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file` or, use `sed -i` (on those platforms where it is supported, but note that there are differences between GNU `sed` and BSD (macOS) `sed`), or `gawk -i inplace` ([GNU Awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16531920/1983854)).

Note in both cases I am using a single command instead of piping to another one.

Comment: You might use a more portable `-E` option instead of `-r`.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks a lot for your thorough edits to remove the links to Docs.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
echo 1.2.3.4 | sed 's/\./_/g' | cut -d "_" -f1,2
```

(Escaped the dot with `\`, and specified the delimiter for `cut`.)

Answer (score 1):

The input is so simple it can be done easily with just `cut` and `tr`.  Use `cut` to pick out the first two fields (delimited by `.`), and then use `tr` to change the dot to an underscore:

```
$ cut -d '.' -f 1,2 input | tr '.' '_'
6_5
6_10
7_2
10_11
```

Comment: Why would you use two processes when there is already a simpler, better explained answer using one.

Comment: @123 I generally try to use tools that are designed to do what I use them for.  Both `sed` and `awk` felt a bit too general. This also way faster than `sed` or `awk` (`sed` being the slowest solution by far).

Comment: @Kusalanda, how have you come to the conclusion that this is faster? Also how are sed and awk not designed to manipulate text?

Comment: @123 By timing my answer and the suggestions made by @fedorqui on 1000000 lines of input.  `awk`: 1.57s, `sed`: 7.74s, `cut`+`tr`: 0.62s

Comment: awk is quickest on my machine for 2048512 lines,(from catting original together)

Comment: @123 `sed` is designed to manipulate text, and `awk` in more or less a general programming language.  In this case though, the input is so simple that regular expression manipulation with `sed` seems overkill.

Comment: `awk in more or less a general programming language`, it's really not, it is 100% designed for text processing.

Comment: @123 I never said it wasn't. What is the real issue that you're getting at here? What's the constructive critique?

Comment: You just did, I even quoted it??

Comment: @123 No, I said what you quoted, which includes simple extraction and manipulation of characters on a line-by-line basis. The Awk language is more general than just using `awk` as a simple stream editor though. That is why I said it's "more or less a general programming language".

Answer (score 0):

My `awk` solution would be :

```
$ echo "6.5.1.2.3
> 6.10.3.9.6
> 7.2.0.0.0
> 10.11.12.13.4" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=".";OFS="_"}{print $1,$2}'
6_5
6_10
7_2
10_11
```