# Replace 2nd line in flat file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I am new bee for shell script. Please redirect me to correct post if this question is redundant.

I have file.txt which has text like below and want to change the 2nd row in file

```
Property1=0
Property2=0 50 14 1/1 * ? *
Property3=0
```

I want to replace 2nd line to change 50 14 to current time,  file will look like

```
Property1=0
Property2=0 58 15 1/1 * ? *
Property3=0
```

and next time it will look like

```
Property1=0
Property2=0 03 16 1/1 * ? *
Property3=0
```

Please help me how to change 2nd line.

Comment: Use `sed '2<command>'` to perform `<command>` on line 2.

Comment: What is the logic that governs what you're replacing and what the replacement is?

Comment: This is cron pattern, which I need to replace in flat file from shell. SO when I execute shell, time should change based on current time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sed to change the second line

```
sed '2s/.*/Property2=0 58 15 1\/1 * ? */' test
```

It seems like you're trying to increment, but I don't see the pattern in the third example

Comment: I think they're times. first number is minutes, second number is hours

Comment: Yeah, looks like some sort of cron job... but how does 58 15 go to 3 16

Comment: The first time is at `15:58`, the next one is at `16:03`

Comment: yes, this is cron job and I am trying to fill minutes and hours. Based on shell when it runs

Answer (score 2):

This is probably easier done using `awk` than `sed`.

```
awk -v min=$(date +%M) -v hour=$(date +%H) 'NR == 2 { $2 = min; $3 = hour } 1' file > file.new
```

The two `date` commands set `awk` variables to the current time. `NR == 2` matches line 2 in the file, then it replaces the 2nd and 3rd fields with those time variables. `1` at the end causes the current line to be printed.

Comment: SO you want me to create a new file "file.new" everytime I want to change this time? If this is the case, then I should go for sed

Comment: Recent versions of GNU awk have an `inplace` option to replace the input file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace

Comment: @ShikhaA even if your awk doesn't have inplace editing, typing `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file` really isn't that much more effort than typing `sed -i tmp 'script' file` especially when the sed script will be less concise than the awk script.