# Matching line and remove that matching line duplicate using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have the configuration file, i want matching particular line like "server.port=5480". Leave that matching first remove rest matching line. Example

```
server.port=5480
server.port=5480
server.port=5480
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"
ssl.use-sslv3 = "disable"
ssl.cipher-list = "FIPS':' +3DES':'!aNULL"
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"
server.port=5480
server.port=5480
server.port=5480
server.port=5480
```

Desired output is only one line

```
server.port=5480
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"
ssl.use-sslv3 = "disable"
ssl.cipher-list = "FIPS':' +3DES':'!aNULL"
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"
```

Using sed I want this and one more this is not sequence line may be it comes variant

Comment: If you are open to a non `sed` solution, you can try piping your output to `sort -u`.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: Sort -u isn't exactly what OP wants since that would coalesce the ENTIRE file and leave just the unique entries. He just wants to remove the cases where there are multiple occurrences one after the other.

Comment: @SatheeshSivaNallathambi It can be used either directly: `sort -u your_file`, or after a pipe: `cat your_file | sort -u`. But as explained by VarunMandalaparthy, all duplicates will be removed, not only the one you want, and the whole file will be sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use `awk` and print all those lines that either do not contain `server.port` or it appears for the first time:

```
$ awk '!(/server.port/ && c++)' file
server.port=5480
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"
ssl.use-sslv3 = "disable"
ssl.cipher-list = "FIPS':' +3DES':'!aNULL"
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"
```

Note I use this approach because I see other lines occurring more than once.

#### How does this work?

A true condition in awk triggers printing the whole line. So if you say `awk '1' file`, all the file will be printed.

What we are doing here is the contrary: limit printing on certain cases. And these cases are when `server.port` occurs for the 2nd, 3rd... time.
Since `/server.port/` matches the lines that have "server.port" in it, we then also check if the variable `c` is positive or not.

- When it is set for the first time we have `!(True && 0++)` which is `!(True && False)` → `!(False)` → `True`.
- In the rest of cases, it is `!(True && positive++)` which is `!(True && True)` → `!(True)` → `False`, so no print is triggered.

Comment: Ya it's work fine, I want write on same file because i am using this file for other system

Comment: @SatheeshSivaNallathambi For inplace modifications check [awk save modifications inplace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16529730/1983854)

Comment: thanks for your code i am running this code for several machine so i can't check is there gawk available there. co is there any other way and i am new in awk can u explain this code especially c++ purpose

Comment: @SatheeshSivaNallathambi in any awk flavour you can say `awk '...' file > tmp_file && tmp_file file`. This will always work. Regarding the code itself, see my update.

Comment: I saw `"gawk -i inplace '{print $1}' file"` this line it's good like `sed  -i` . Thank for your code and explanation also now i understand