# Is it possible to insert new column in input file using awk?

Tags: unix, awk

My input file is as below

file name: marksheet

```
No         Name       Sub1     Sub2    Sub3
1          Atul       89        56      78
2          Jay        56        88      75
3          Mariya     85        75      56
4          Nita       90        88      95
```

Now i want to perform total and percentage.
So i performed below command

```
awk 'total=$3+$4+$5, per=total/3 {print total "\t" per}' marksheet
```

it gives output of total and column. as

```
223       74.3333
219       73
216       72
273       91
```

So now i want to add above column( output) in file marksheet. So if it is possible then how to perform the command using awk.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace I'm quoting: _In latest GNU Awk (since 4.1.0 released), it has the option of "inplace" file editing - -_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin statement is to define header of the file. you have already calculated sum and average. Printed `$0` means whole line and then `total` and then `per` variables which contains value of sum and average value. `OFS` here make `awk` aware of the output fields to be separated using tab.

```
awk  -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN{print "No         Name       Sub1     Sub2    Sub3    total    percent"} NR>1{total=$3+$4+$5; per=total/3 ;print $0 ,total,per }' marksheet
No         Name       Sub1     Sub2    Sub3     total   percent
1          Atul       89        56      78      223     74.3333
2          Jay        56        88      75      219     73
3          Mariya     85        75      56      216     72
4          Nita       90        88      95      273     91
```

To actually modify your base file:

```
awk  -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN{print "No         Name       Sub1     Sub2    Sub3    total    percent"} NR>1{total=$3+$4+$5; per=total/3 ;print $0 ,total,per }' marksheet >marksheet.tmp && mv marksheet.tmp marksheet
```

Comment: Sir actually i want to insert total and percentage columns in the file "marksheet" not in output only.

Comment: Nice attempt, but printf in awk would have simplified it!

Answer (score 0):

As I had never used the `-i` switch and inplace editing (in Gnu awk since v. 4.1.0 (`gawk -V`), according to [awk save modifications in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace)) I decided to take it for a spin.  I took OP's example data and code and went with it:

```
$ awk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak 'NR==1 && $6="total", $7="per"; NR>1 && $6=$3+$4+$5, $7=$6/3' OFS='\t' file
$ cat file
No      Name    Sub1    Sub2    Sub3    total   per
1       Atul    89      56      78      223     74.3333
2       Jay     56      88      75      219     73
3       Mariya  85      75      56      216     72
4       Nita    90      88      95      273     91
```

And the backup:

```
$ cat file.bak
No         Name       Sub1     Sub2    Sub3
1          Atul       89        56      78
2          Jay        56        88      75
3          Mariya     85        75      56
4          Nita       90        88      95
```

Spacing difference comes from real tabs in output vs. cut'n pasting the question for input.