# Edit file with Bash

Tags: bash

I want to update files values used for database connection in this file:

```
./software/config/database.yml
```

***file content:***

```
base: &base
  adapter: mysql2
  username: root
  password:
```

How I can set username and password using bash?

Comment: What about `vim`, `nano`, `emacs`, etc? That question seems off-topic

Comment: I want to do this using script because I have this file in many locations.

Comment: so then you should clearly specify your intentions. As of now, your problem is solvable with a single text editor

Comment: Can you show me a solution with bash script?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: '/username/{$2=" NEWUSER"} /password:/{$2=" NEWPASS"}1' inputfile
base: &base
  adapter: mysql2
  username: NEWUSER
  password: NEWPASS
```

If new username and password are stored in a variable :

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: -v newPass=" NEWPASS" -v newUser=" NEWUSER" '/username/{$2=newUser} /password:/{$2=newPass}1' input
```

For editing file:

```
 awk -F: -v OFS=: -v newPass=" NEWPASS" -v newUser=" NEWUSER" '/username/{$2=newUser} /password:/{$2=newPass}1' inputfile > user.tmp && mv user.tmp inputfile
```

Comment: One question how I can define the variables at the beginning of the bash script?

Comment: you can use `-v newPass="$variable"` in second awk command.where $variable store value of password. you can define it anywhere before execution of this awk command.

Comment: How I can save the changes into the file?

Comment: if your `awk` supports `-i` option then  you can do inplace replacement. Other wise you can do check update.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace) for info on Gnu awk's `inplace`.edit.