# awk comand for inserting new column in csv

Tags: csv, awk, command-line, terminal, command

I'm using this command line I found on internet to add a new column in a csv file:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,F,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16}' FS=, OFS=, F='0' file.csv
```

So the problem is this line only prints the result in terminal but I want to modify the file.csv, would this be possible?
Further more when I execute this command line the output I get is this:

original CSV:

```
11;ALE;Augsburg;1;Jentzsch;Simon Jentzsch;35;28;28;28;0;2520;1;0;-41;t
11;ALE;Augsburg;2;Verhaegh;Paul Johannes Gerardus Verhaegh;28;26;26;25;0;2333;3;0;1;t
11;ALE;Augsburg;18;Callsen-Bracker;Jan-Ingwer Callsen-Bracker;27;30;25;24;5;2310;7;0;4;t
```

Terminal Output:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,;Jentzsch;Simon Jentzsch;35;28;28;28;0;2520;1;0;-41;t
,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,;Verhaegh;Paul Johannes Gerardus Verhaegh;28;26;26;25;0;2333;3;0;1;t
,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,8;Callsen-Bracker;Jan-Ingwer Callsen-Bracker;27;30;25;24;5;2310;7;0;4;t
```

It is hard to explain but what I wanted was something like that:

```
11;ALE;Augsburg;1;Jentzsch;Simon Jentzsch;35;28;28;28;0;0;2520;1;0;-41;t
11;ALE;Augsburg;2;Verhaegh;Paul Johannes Gerardus Verhaegh;28;26;26;25;0;0;2333;3;0;1;t
11;ALE;Augsburg;18;Callsen-Bracker;Jan-Ingwer Callsen-Bracker;27;30;25;24;5;0;2310;7;0;4;t
```

So just add a 0 as a new column after the original 11th column.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like,

```
$ awk -F";" -v OFS=";" '$11=$11OFS"0"' file
11;ALE;Augsburg;1;Jentzsch;Simon Jentzsch;35;28;28;28;0;0;2520;1;0;-41;t
11;ALE;Augsburg;2;Verhaegh;Paul Johannes Gerardus Verhaegh;28;26;26;25;0;0;2333;3;0;1;t
11;ALE;Augsburg;18;Callsen-Bracker;Jan-Ingwer Callsen-Bracker;27;30;25;24;5;0;2310;7;0;4;t
```

---

You won't be able to redirect the output to the file as we are reading from the same file, so we can redirect it to a new file and move the new file as old file.

**Example**

```
$ awk -F";" -v OFS=";" '$11=$11OFS"0"' file > new_file && mv new_file file
```

**Edit**

If you are using awk version `4.1.0` or later, you can use `-i` option as well.

```
$ awk -i inplace -F";" -v OFS=";" '$11=$11OFS"0"{print}' file
```

which will edit the file in place. Thanks @JamesBrown for the link.

Comment: It's okey if we redirect the result to new file, I can delete later the old version

Comment: @JamesBrown wired. It worked fine while I was testing :/

Comment: @yeker3 You can use normal shell redirections. `awk .... file > new_file`  and use `mv` to replace the file `mv new_file file`

Comment: There is also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16531920/4162356) if you are using new enough Gnu awk.

Comment: @JamesBrown ohh, that was something new to me. Thanks for the link.

Comment: how do I know my awk version? @JamesBrown , I need the inplace option, in order of modifying several csv at once :/

Comment: @yeker3 `awk --version` or `awk -V`

Comment: `awk version 20070501` what version is this :')

Comment: @yeker3 The inplace option is available only on gnu awk. I guess you are using BSD version. If you are on mac os you can install gawk and try this

Comment: how can I install it? sorry I'm asking too many things, just newbie

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'a;b;c;d' | awk '{sub(/([^;]*;){2}/,"&0;")}1'
a;b;0;c;d
```

Just change the 2 to 11 or whatever...