# rearranging column based on condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, awk

I have a *.csv file. with value as below

```
"ASDP02","8801942183589"

"ASDP06","8801939151023"

"CSDP04","8801963981740"

"ASDP09","8801946305047"

"ASDP12","8801941195677"

"ASDP05","8801922826186"

"CSDP08","8801983008938"

"ASDP04","8801944346555"

"CSDP11","8801910831518"
```

or sometimes the value is as below

```
"8801989353984","KSDP05" 

"8801957608165","ASDP11" 

"8801991455848","CSDP10" 

"8801981363116","CSDP07" 

"8801921247870","KSDP07" 

"8801965386240","CSDP06" 

"8801956293036","KSDP10" 

"8801984383904","KSDP11" 

"8801944211742","ASDP09"
```

I just want to put the numeric value (e.g. 8801989353984) always in 1st column. Is it possible using BASH script?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't parse CSV in Bash, as it is difficult to write a good parser in Bash for the general case where the cells may contain newlines, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash can do the work but awk might be a better choice for rearrange your file:

sample.csv:

```
"ASDP02","8801942183589"
"8801944211742","ASDP09"
```

command:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{$1=$1;if(substr($1, 2, length($1) - 2) + 0 == substr($1, 2, length($1) - 2)){print $1,$2}else{print $2,$1}}' sample.csv
```

- `substr($1, 2, length($1) - 2) + 0 == substr($1, 2, length($1) - 2)` checks the column is numeric or not. If it is, print the original line otherwise switch column1 and column2

Output:

```
"8801942183589","ASDP02"
"8801944211742","ASDP09"
```

Comment: I just want to rearrange the column with numeric value in 1st column wherever the column is in the csv file

Comment: @KaziNymulHaqueKanon check it now. I thought they are in the different files

Comment: Suppose there is 3 columns and i want to get the same output as before.                                                                                                                                "KSDP10","20","1910427539"
"KSDP10","20","1910427642"
"KSDP10","20","1910427666"
"KSDP10","20","1910427704"
"KSDP10","20","1910427720"
"KSDP10","20","1910427738"
"KSDP10","20","1910427936"
"KSDP10","20","1910428023"
"KSDP10","20","1910428046"

Answer (score 1):

`Sed` is also your friend here

**Input**

```
cat 41189347
"ASDP02","8801942183589"
"ASDP06","8801939151023"
"CSDP04","8801963981740"
"ASDP09","8801946305047"
"ASDP12","8801941195677"
"ASDP05","8801922826186"
"CSDP08","8801983008938"
"ASDP04","8801944346555"
"CSDP11","8801910831518"
```

**Script**

```
sed -E 's/^("[[:alpha:]]+.*"),("[[:digit:]]+")$/\2,\1/' 41189347
```

**Output**

```
"8801942183589","ASDP02"
"8801939151023","ASDP06"
"8801963981740","CSDP04"
"8801946305047","ASDP09"
"8801941195677","ASDP12"
"8801922826186","ASDP05"
"8801983008938","CSDP08"
"8801944346555","ASDP04"
"8801910831518","CSDP11"
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '$1~/[A-Z]/{t=$2;$2=$1;$1=t}1' file
```

if first field has alpha chars, swap first and second columns and print.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands assume that the cells in the CSV files do not contain newlines and commas. Otherwise, you should write a more complicated script in Perl, PHP, or other programming language capable of parsing CSV files properly. But Bash, definitely, is not appropriate for this task.

---

**Perl**

```
perl -F, -nle '@F = reverse @F if $F[0] =~ /^"\d+"$/;
print join(",", @F)' file
```

*Beware*, If the cells contain newlines, or commas, use Perl's `Text::CSV` module, for instance. Although it is a simple task in Perl, it goes beyond the scope of the current question.

The command splits the input lines by commas (`-F,`) and stores the result into `@F` array, for each line. The items in the array are reversed, if the first field `$F[0]` matches the regular expression. You can also swap the items this way: `($F[0], $F[1]) = ($F[1], $F[0])`.

Finally, the joins the array items with commas, and prints *to the standard output*.

If you want to edit the file in-place, use `-i` option: `perl -i.backup -F, ...`.

**AWK**

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '/^"[0-9]+",/ {print; next}
{ t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print }' file
```

The input and output field separators are set to `,` with `-F,` and `-vOFS=,`.

If the line matches the pattern `/^"[0-9]+",/` (the line begins with a "numeric" CSV column), the script prints the record and advances to the `next` record. Otherwise the next block is executed.

In the next block, it swaps the first two columns and prints the result *to the standard output*.

If you want to edit the file in-place, see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pure bash script to generate other file which has the structure you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

csv_file="/path/to/your/csvfile"
output_file="/path/to/output_file"

#Optional
rm -rf "${output_file}"

readarray -t LINES < <(cat < "${csv_file}" 2> /dev/null)

for item in "${LINES[@]}"; do

  if [[ $item =~ ^\"([0-9A-Z]+)\"\,\"([0-9]+)\" ]]; then
    echo "\"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}\",\"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\"" >> "${output_file}"
  else
    echo "$item" >> "${output_file}"
  fi
done
```

This works even if your file is "mixed" I mean with some lines in the right format and other lines in the bad format.