# Update a specific line with data under queueFilters section only

Tags: linux, shell

I have file and content has like below.

```
------------------------------------------------

##
servers:
# Start OF VM1
 - host: "VM1"
   queueFilters: 
       include: ["*"]
   channelFilters: 
       include: ["*"]
# End OF VM1

# Start OF VM2
- host: "VM2"
   queueFilters: 
       include: ["*"]
   channelFilters: 
       include: ["*"]
# End OF VM2
---------------------------------------------------
```

I wanted to update parameter like include under queueFilter section : `["test1","test2","test3"]` only between the lines where from `# Start OF VM1` to # `End OF VM1`

I tried with the command,

```
V1=VM1
V2="test1","test2","test3"

awk -F': ' '/# Start OF '$V1'/,/# End OF '$V1'/{if( $0 ~/include/ ) {if ( $2 ~ /\[\]/ ) {gsub(/\]/,"'$V2']")} else {gsub(/\]/,",'$V2']")}}}1' input.yaml
```

Could some one help me how to achieve this..

Comment: `[` and `]` have special meaning in regular expressions, you need to escape them.

Comment: Hi Barmar, the line should required to update like include: ["test1","test2","test3"]

Comment: Hi Barmar, the line should required to update like include: ["*","test1","test2","test3"]

Comment: Hi Barmar, It's not duplicate question, ,my requirement is some thing new.

Comment: I think your code will work correctly if you use the variables correctly, as explained in the duplicate.

Comment: If it doesn't, edit the question to show the new code and I'll reopen.

Comment: no, my code updating both queuFilter section and channelFilter section..I don't want to update channel filter section.
 queueFilters: 
       include: ["*"]
   channelFilters: 
       include: ["*"]

output :
# Start OF VM1
 - host: "VM1"
   queueFilters: 
       include: ["*","test1",test2","tes3"]
   channelFilters: 
       include: ["*"]
# End OF VM1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should assign the shell variables to `awk` variables, rather than trying to substitute shell variables into the script.

Second, if you only want to update `queueFilters`, you need to match that. You can set a variable that will be used when you get to the `include` line.

```
V1=VM1
V2='"test1","test2","test3"'

awk -F': ' -v V2="$V2" '
    /# Start OF '$V1'/,/# End OF '$V1'/ {
        if (/queueFilters:/) {inqueue = 1}
        else if ($1 ~ /include/ && inqueue) {
             if ( $2 ~ /\[\]/ ) {
                gsub(/\]/, V2 "]")
             } else {
                gsub(/\]/, "," V2 "]")
             }
             inqueue = 0
        }
    }1' input.yaml
```

Comment: I am sorry, I did  not under under stand on your second point.

Comment: See the line `if ($1 == "queueFilter")`. It sets the variable `inqueue`, and then we check that variable when we see `include`.

Comment: Yeah, got the logic. But nothing is changed with the command. I had set the variables...

Comment: I fixed it. I needed to use `~` instead of `==` because the spaces at the beginning of the line are part of the field.

Comment: Yes, it's working fine as expected.. Thank you very much..!!

Comment: You mean how to overwrite the original file? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place

Comment: No, I mean, the current command appending the data for the line   include: ["*","test1","test2","test3"].. I want to replace the data like include: ["test1","test2","test3"]... Note : - removed "*" values

Comment: It's working with the below command..
awk -F': ' -v V2="$V2" '
    /# Start OF '$V1'/,/# End OF '$V1'/ {
        if (/queueFilters:/) {inqueue = 1}
        else if ($1 ~ /include/ && inqueue) {
             if ($2 ~ /\[*\]/ ) {
                gsub(/\"\*\"\]/, V2 "]")
             }
             inqueue = 0
        } }1' config.yaml
It's working...