# Using AWK to replace some special codes

Tags: bash, awk

lets say I have a file called somedata.txt, I am trying to replace:

\"

with

"

i.e. removing the \
I am trying to do this using AWK. Can you please help?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I'm really not good with this, I am not sure how to handle the syntax. Trying to use octal code:
awk '{gsub("\134\042","\042")}1' somedata.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to escape both characters `\` and `"` like shown below

```
awk '{gsub("\\\\\"", "\"")}1' somedata.txt
```

Or if you can use `sed` it becomes simpler

```
sed 's/\\"/"/g' somedata.txt
```

`sed` also allows inplace editing (flag `-i`) to update original files

```
sed -i 's/\\"/"/g' somedata.txt
```

Comment: In awk slashed regexp not quoted string containing regexp gets closer: `awk '{gsub(/\\"/,"\"")}1'` or `awk -vq=\" '{gsub(/\\"/,q)}1'` and [_recent gawk_ has inplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place/)

Comment: Thank you both. @Pradip I've never used sed, is there a way to combine two find/replace and update the original file? I also need to replace \n with a new line. I was achieving that with awk using: awk '{gsub(/\\n/,"\n")}1' somedata.txt

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thanks for pointers

@CharlieC:  Multiple find/replace expressions can be combined using semicolon `;` (in both `sed` and `awk`)
In this case,  `awk -i inplace '{gsub(/\\"/,"\""); gsub(/\\n/,"\n")}1'  somedata.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can also open file in **vim** editor and try this:
Press esc and then

```
:%s_oldString_newString_g
```

For your case, it's

```
:%s_\\\"_\"_g
```

Since " and \ are special characters, you need to add a \ before the chars to make the command execute.