# replace column name with file name shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sed

How to replace the 2nd column name in a .csv file with its corresponding file name for all files within a directory? 
Does anyone know how to do this with shell scripting? sed or awk

input file name CDXV1.csv

```
Gene,RPKM(26558640 pairs)
ENSTGUG00000013338 (GAPDH),971.678203888
ENSTGUG00000005054 (CAMKV),687.81249397
ENSTGUG00000006651 (ARPP19),634.296191033
ENSTGUG00000002582 (ITM2A),613.756010638
```

output file name CDXV1.csv (same)

```
Gene,CDXV1(26558640 pairs)
ENSTGUG00000013338 (GAPDH),971.678203888
ENSTGUG00000005054 (CAMKV),687.81249397
ENSTGUG00000006651 (ARPP19),634.296191033
ENSTGUG00000002582 (ITM2A),613.756010638
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Post your research attempts even if they aren't successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***sed*** solution:

```
for f in yourdir/*.csv; do sed -i "1s~^\([^,]*\),\([^(]*\)~\1,${f%%.*}~g" "$f"; done
```

---

*Details*:

- `for f in yourdir/*.csv` - iterating through *csv* filenames
- `-i` - modify the file in-place
- `1s` - perform substitution only on the 1st line
- `~` - used as *sed* subcommand sections separator
- `^\([^,]*\),\([^(]*\)` - capturing the 1st field and 2nd field value (till encountering `(`)
- `${f%%.*}` - bash variable substitution, truncate right of the first `.`

Comment: That worked! thanks! Would you mind explaining the command? I'm just getting into this stuff.

Comment: @MadzaYasodaraFariasVirgens, yes, see my details

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=,  'NR==1{split(FILENAME,a,".");split($2,b,"(");$2= a[1] "(" b[2]}1' CDXV1.csv
Gene,CDXV1(26558640 pairs)
ENSTGUG00000013338 (GAPDH),971.678203888
ENSTGUG00000005054 (CAMKV),687.81249397
ENSTGUG00000006651 (ARPP19),634.296191033
ENSTGUG00000002582 (ITM2A),613.756010638
```

If your `awk` support inplace replacement then use `-i inplace` :

```
awk -i inplace -F, -v OFS=,  'NR==1{split(FILENAME,a,".");split($2,b,"(");$2= a[1] "(" b[2]}1' *.csv
```

Comment: OP needs to apply this for all `.csv` files and also someway to modify the file in-place.

Comment: Thank you for nice code PS, could you please let me know which version of awk supports this, as I have gawk 4.0.1 and it is not having this option.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 In latest GNU Awk (since 4.1.0 released), it has the option of "inplace" file editing  check for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place