# How to delete blocks of lines in a file using bash with a pattern and save the remaining on another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am currently working on a script that would delete blocks of lines with specific pattern from **file1.txt** and save the remaining on **file2.txt**. Below is the example of a **file1.txt**:

```
dn: fssecPermissionId=FSNASVIEW,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Securi
 ty,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: FSNASVIEW
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_1

dn: fssecPermissionId=FSNASMANAGE,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Securi
 ty,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: FSNASMANAGE
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_2

dn: fssecPermissionId=permission1,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Securi
 ty,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: permission1
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_3

dn: fssecPermissionId=CMPlanManagementmonitor,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Securi
 ty,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: CMPlanManagementmonitor
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_4

dn: fssecPermissionId=permission2,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Securi
 ty,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: permission2
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_5
```

I would like to delete blocks with `fssecPermissionId=FSNASVIEW`, `fssecPermissionId=FSNASMANAGE` and `fssecPermissionId=CMPlanManagementmonitor`

> Note that there are over 70 values of `fssecPermissionId` that i
>   would like to delete, I just gave few examples for simplicity. I am
>   thinking also that those 70 values would be stored somehow on an array
>   but i have no idea how to.

Below is the expected output that will be saved to **file2.txt**

```
dn: fssecPermissionId=permission1,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Securi
 ty,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: permission1
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_3

dn: fssecPermissionId=permission2,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Securi
 ty,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: permission2
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_5
```

Thank you so much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` with an empty `RS`:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/fssecPermissionId=(FSNASVIEW|FSNASMANAGE|CMPlanManagementmonitor)/' file

dn: fssecPermissionId=permission1,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Securi
 ty,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: permission1
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_3

dn: fssecPermissionId=permission2,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Securi
 ty,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: permission2
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_5
```

To save changes check: [awk save modifications in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place)

---

**EDIT:** If you are dealing with a big list of exclusion patter then create a file called `excl.txt` with all the strings you want to exclude like this:

```
cat excl.txt
FSNASVIEW
FSNASMANAGE
CMPlanManagementmonitor
```

Then use this awk command:

```
awk -F, -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==FNR {
   ex["dn: fssecPermissionId=" $1]
   next
}
!($1 in ex)' excl.txt RS= file

dn: fssecPermissionId=permission1,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Securi
 ty,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: permission1
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_3

dn: fssecPermissionId=permission2,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Securi
 ty,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: permission2
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_5
```

Comment: This will work if `fssecPermissionId` has only 3 values, however, in my real file, i have over 70 values of `fssecPermissionId` to delete. is there a way to restrict those 70 values using this code?

Comment: This definitely works! thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

file:

```
dn: fssecPermissionId=FSNASVIEW,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: FSNASVIEW
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_1

dn: fssecPermissionId=FSNASMANAGE,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: FSNASMANAGE
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_2

dn: fssecPermissionId=permission1,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: permission1
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_3

dn: fssecPermissionId=CMPlanManagementmonitor,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: CMPlanManagementmonitor
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_4

dn: fssecPermissionId=permission2,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: permission2
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_5
```

with `sed`:

```
sed -r /"fssecPermissionId=(FSNASVIEW|FSNASMANAGE|CMPlanManagementmonitor)"/,+4d file
```

output:

```
dn: fssecPermissionId=permission1,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: permission1
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_3

dn: fssecPermissionId=permission2,fsFragmentId=Permissions,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
fssecPermissionId: permission2
objectClass: FSSecPermission
fssecAssignedGroupRoleRef: group_5
```

Comment: This will work if `fssecPermissionId` has only 3 values, however, in my real file, i have over 70 values of `fssecPermissionId` to delete. is there a way to restrict those 70 values using this code?