# Delete everything after a certain line in bash

Tags: bash, text

I was wondering if there was a way to delete everything after a certain line of a text file in bash. So say there's a text file with 10 lines, and I want to delete every line after line number 4, so only the first 4 lines remained, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: post the input example

Comment: What do you mean input example? There would be a file with a lot of lines, named say file.txt, and I just want to trim all text after a certain line.

Comment: simplest is `head -4 oldfile > newfile`, then `mv newfile oldfile`.  That's not "in place", but not sure what that would be necessary anyway.

Answer (score 10):

You can use GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i '5,$d' file.txt
```

That is, `5,$` means the range line 5 until the end, and `d` means to delete.
Only the first 4 lines will remain.
The `-i` flag tells `sed` to edit the file in-place.

If you have only BSD `sed`, then the `-i` flag requires a backup file suffix:

```
sed -i.bak '5,$d' file.txt
```

As [@ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient) pointed out, while this solution is simple,
it's inefficient because `sed` will still read the input until the end of the file, which is unnecessary.

As [@agc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6136214/agc) pointed out, the inverse logic of my first proposal might be actually more intuitive. That is, do not print by default (`-n` flag),
and explicitly print range `1,4`:

```
sed -ni.bak 1,4p file.txt
```

Another simple alternative, assuming that the first 4 lines are not excessively long and so they easily fit in memory, and also assuming that the 4th line ends with a newline character,
you can read the first 4 lines into memory and then overwrite the file:

```
lines=$(head -n 4 file.txt)
echo "$lines" > file.txt
```

Comment: Note that on *BSD (including OS X), `sed -i '5,$d' file.txt` will use `'5,$d'` as the backup suffix and `file.txt` as the expression, which is not what you want. There is no simple portable way to perform an in-place `sed` without creating backup files.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question.

Comment: The logical contrary version of this answer seems more intuitive:  `sed -ni.bak '1,4p' file.txt`

Answer (score 4):

Minor refinements on [*Janos*' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45125832/6136214), [*ephemient*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45126065/6136214), and [*cdark's* comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125826/delete-everything-after-a-certain-line-in-bash/45129895#comment77223248_45125826):

1. Simpler (and faster) `sed` code:

   ```
   sed -i 4q file
   ```
2. When a filter util can't directly edit a file, there's
   [`sponge`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

   ```
   head -4 file | sponge file
   ```
3. Most efficient for *Linux* might be **`truncate`** -- [coreutils](http://gnu.org/software/coreutils) sibling util to `fallocate`, which offers the same minimal *I/O* of *ephemient*'s more  portable, (but more  complex), `dd`-based answer:

   ```
   truncate -s `head -4 file | wc -c` file
   ```

Answer (score 3):

If I don't know the line number, merely the line content (I need to know that there is nothing below the line containing 'knowntext' that I want to preserve.), then I use.

```
sed -i '/knowntext/,$d' inputfilename
```

to directly alter the file, or to be cautious

```
sed '/knowntext/,$d' inputfilename > outputfilename
```

where inputfilename is unaltered, and outputfilename contains the truncated version of the input.
I am not competent to comment on the efficiency of this, but I know that files of 20kB or so are dealt with faster than I can blink.

Comment: This is great, but please note that the line containing "knowntext" will also be removed.

Answer (score 2):

The `sed` method that [@janos](https://stackoverflow.com/u/641955) is simple but inefficient. It will read every line from the original file, even ones it could ignore (although that can be fixed using `4q`), and `-i` actually creates a new file (which it renames to replace the original file). And there's the annoying bit where you need to use `sed -i '5,$d' file.txt` with GNU sed but `sed -i '' '5,$d' file.txt` with BSD sed in order to remove the existing file instead of leaving a backup.

Another method that performs less I/O:

```
dd bs=1 count=0 if=/dev/null of=file.txt \
    seek=$(grep -b ^ file.txt | tail -n+5 | head -n1 | cut -d: -f1)
```

- `grep -b ^ file.txt` prints out byte offsets on each line, e.g.

  ```
  $ yes | grep -b ^
  0:y
  2:y
  4:y
  ...
  ```
- `tail -n+5` skips the first 4 lines, outputting the 5<sup>th</sup> and subsequent lines
- `head -n1` takes only the next line (e.g. only the 5<sup>th</sup> line)

  After `head` reads the one line, it will exit. This causes `tail` to exit because it has nowhere to output to anymore. This causes `grep` to exit for the same reason. Thus, the rest of `file.txt` does not need to be examined.
- `cut -d: -f1` takes only the first part before the `:` (the byte offset)
- `dd bs=1 count=0 if=/dev/null of=file.txt seek=N`

  - using a block size of 1 byte, seek to block `N` of `file.txt`
  - copy 0 blocks of size 1 byte from `/dev/null` to `file.txt`
  - truncate `file.txt` here (because `conv=notrunc` was not given)

  In short, this removes all data on the 5<sup>th</sup> and subsequent lines from `file.txt`.

  On Linux there is a command named `fallocate` which can similarly extend or truncate a file, but that's not portable.

UNIX filesystems support efficiently truncating files in-place, and these commands are portable. The downside is that it's more work to write out.

(Also, `dd` will print some unnecessary stats to stderr, and will exit with an error if the file has fewer than 5 lines, although in that case it will leave the existing file contents in place, so the behavior is still correct. Those can be addressed also, if needed.)

Comment: A simpler way than `seek=$(grep -b ^ file.txt | tail -n+5 | head -n1 | cut -d: -f1)` is `seek=$(head -n4 file.txt | wc -c | tr -d ' ')`

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk (v. 4.1.0+, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place)). First we create a test file (NOTICE THE DISCLAIMER):

```
$ seq 1 10 > file     # THIS WILL OVERWRITE FILE NAMED file WITH TEST DATA
```

Then the code and validation (WILL MODIFY THE ORIGINAL FILE NAMED `file`):

```
$ awk -i inplace 'NR<=4' file
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -i inplace '   # edit is targetted to the original file (try without -i ...)
NR<=4                # output first 4 records
' file               # file
```

You could also exit on line `NR==5` which would be quicker if you redirected the output of the program to a new file (remove `#` for action) which would be the same as `head -4 file > new_file`:

```
$ awk 'NR==5{exit}1' file  # > new_file
```

When testing, don't forget the `seq` part first.