# Sed inside an awk statement

Tags: awk, sed

I'd like to perform a series of sed commands on lines of a file roster.txt only beginning with a keyword. For example:

```
Employee : Kiara 20 hours@8.25
Employee : Connor 25 hours@8.00
Employee : Dylan 30 hours@9.00
```

Becomes:

```
Employee : Kiara_20_hoursat8dot25
Employee : Connor_25_hoursat8dot00
Employee : Dylan_30_hoursat9dot00
```

I know the sed commands to make the changes I just wanted a way to peform them on lines starting with "employee". Maybe

```
awk '$1 == "Employee" {sed -i -e 's/\./dot/g' roster.txt}' roster.txt
```

Comment: Are you locked with sed/awk or do you take any shell script line as solution?

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk and you certainly never need to call sed from within awk!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ cat roster.txt
foo : bar@baz.123
Employee : Kiara 20 hours@8.25
Employee : Connor 25 hours@8.00
Employee : Dylan 30 hours@9.00

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" : "} $1=="Employee"{gsub(/ /,"_",$2); gsub(/@/,"at",$2); gsub(/\./,"dot",$2)} 1' roster.txt
foo : bar@baz.123
Employee : Kiara_20_hoursat8dot25
Employee : Connor_25_hoursat8dot00
Employee : Dylan_30_hoursat9dot00
```

`awk` supports substitution commands as well - `sub` to replace first occurrence and `gsub` to replace all occurrences. Also allows to change only specific field

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=" : "}` use  `:`  as input/output field separator
- `gsub(/ /,"_",$2)` replace all spaces with `_` only for second field
- Similarly other substitutions as required
- `1` at end of command is idiomatic way to print the line, includes any changes made
- See also [awk save modifications in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place)

Comment: will this write to the original file?

Comment: @cbrad97 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place

Comment: so if i dont have GAWK 4.1 or later, i need to create a temp file to write to? I kind of need the original name of the file to be intact

Comment: @cbrad97 the second answer there suggests the way to do it... `awk ... roster.txt > tmp && mv tmp roster.txt`... the `-i inplace` option with gawk does the same

Answer (score 2):

I'd write:

```
sed '/^Employee :/ {s/@/at/; s/\./dot/; s/ /_/3g}' <<END
Employee : Kiara 20 hours@8.25
Employee : Connor 25 hours@8.00
Employee : Dylan 30 hours@9.00
Foo : bar baz@qux.blah
END
```

```
Employee : Kiara_20_hoursat8dot25
Employee : Connor_25_hoursat8dot00
Employee : Dylan_30_hoursat9dot00
Foo : bar baz@qux.blah
```

Requires GNU sed for the `3g` modifier of the `s` command

Comment: good one, though I'd have used `!b` see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands

Comment: Does next record mean next file or next line in the current file? When i run the command, !n is replaced with another filename?

Comment: I think that's bash doing [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction), where `!n` is your previous command that begins with "n". Try turning hist expansion off with `set +H` (turn it on after with `set -H`)

Comment: @glennjackman in fact it has to be `!b` not `!n`, for example try two consecutive lines not starting with `Employee`... and history expansion won't come into picture inside single quotes

Answer (score 0):

You really do not need to use both tools, either will do everything you need.

sed solution:

```
 sed -i -e 's/^Employee : \([^ ]*\) \([0-9]*\) hours@\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]*\)/Employee : \1_\2_hoursat\3dot\4/' roster.txt
```

Edit after comment:

If you want a very generic replacement using only sed that works on your sample:

```
sed -i -e 's/\([^:]\) \([^:]\)/\1_\2/g' -e 's/@/at/g' -e 's/\./dot/g' roster.txt
```

Comment: What if i dont know the fields following the colon? I just know that I have a series of sed substitutions to perform on any text following the colon.

Comment: make the pattern more generic. You want to the and keep the patter as restrictive as possible while still capturing all your case the last thing you want is for a substitution to occur that you did not intend. I will add another option that will work on the sample but could be riskier.