# Using grep and sed to substitude a string?

Tags: bash, sed, find

I'm fairly new to writing bash and I'm a bit confused on the errors/problem with my code. I have two main problems. In case `P)` I would like to see if a certain file exist. If it exist I would like to update the `balance` with the `newbalance`.

```
P) read -p "Enter email: " email
   read -p "Enter payment amount: " payment
   newbalance=$(echo $payment + $balance | bc)
   if [ -f $email ]; then
       sed -i "s/$balance/$newbalance/" $email
       #also tried
       #find . -type f -name "$email" -exec sed -i "s/${balance}{newbalance}/" {} \;
   else
       echo -e "Error: customer not found\n\n"
   fi
   balance=$newbalance
   continue
   ;;
```

when I try to read in a `payment` such as `100.00` I receive an error:

```
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

The file format its self is pretty simple and the balance only appears once.

```
email  name
apt-XX rent balance duedate
```

The code worked when I redirected echo's to modify the file. Now that I've tried to implement `sed` the code has stopped working, I'm unsure of what is causing it. I've tried using `find` with `sed` but that isn't working either. I've looked at multiple stack overflow questions but the examples are similar to mine.

This is one of the files I'm dealing with

```
jboat@xyz.com John Boat
APT-5B 1100.00 100.00 2017-10-02
```

Comment: You have spaces between `newbalance` and `=`. Should be `newbalance=$(...`

Comment: `newbalance` is a registered trademark. You should probably use a different variable name before you end up in troubles.

Comment: Include a sample set of lines from your file so that it is clear what kind of data you are dealing with.

Comment: @codeforester I've added an example of a file (where the email is also the file name).

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash to do the calculation, no need for bc.

```
newbalance=$((payment + balance))
```

The sed command is ok, you probably got the error because one of the variables contained crap.

Comment: This still seems to give me an error `./menu.bash: line 32: 130.00: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".00").` I was under the impression that I needed bc for floats @yacc.

Comment: Ok I thought it's all integers. Then do a `echo "s/$balance/$newbalance/"` to check what sed gets as regex. @below_avg_st

Comment: With the echo I'm getting `(standard_in) 2: syntax error s// sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression`  @yacc .

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason you're getting that error is because `$balance` is empty. For example:

```
$ echo 100.00 | sed 's//200.00/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

(The echo is just there because sed expects input no matter what.)

So you'll need to track where `$balance` is getting its value and make sure that's not failing.

But, since it's still going to be prone to failure, I'd suggest a slightly more resilient approach using AWK instead:

```
awk -v newbalance="$newbalance" 'FNR==2 {$3=newbalance; print;}' "$email" > "$email.tmp" && mv "$email.tmp" "$email"
```

This sets an awk variable called `newbalance` to the value of the bash variable `$newbalance` and then runs the script. The `FNR` tells it which line to read (in this case the 2nd line in the file), and `$3=newbalance` changes the value of the 3rd field in that line to the value we passed in earlier.

The `mv` at the end is just because older versions of awk can't edit files in place. See: [awk save modifications in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place)

Be warned that if you go down this rabbit hole, you might end up rewriting the entire script in awk before you're done. For inspiration, you could start with moving the arithmetic into awk itself:

```
awk -v payment="$payment" 'FNR==2 {$3+=payment; print;}' "$email" > "$email.tmp" && mv "$email.tmp" "$email"
```