# Reformat date in text file (.csv) with sed and date

Tags: shell, datetime, awk, sed, command-line

This is the input .csv file

```
"item1","10/11/2017 2:10pm",1,2, ...
"item2","10/12/2017 3:10pm",3,4, ...
.
.
.
```

Now, I want to convert the second column (date) to this specific format
`date -d '10/12/2017 2:10pm' +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'`, so that **"10/12/2017 2:10pm"** converts to **"2017/10/12 14:10:00"**

Expecting output file

```
"item1","2017/10/11 14:10:00",1,2, ...
"item2","2017/10/12 15:10:00",3,4, ...
.
.
.
```

I know it can be done by using bash or python, but I want to do it in **one-line command**. Any ideas? Is there a way to pass `date` result to `sed`?

Comment: @MarcLambrichs, The OP didn't mention `awk`, so why add that tag?

Comment: Because OP states *I want to do it in one-line command. Any ideas?*. That's why.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs, [“Did You Lose the Keys Here?” *“No, But the Light Is Much Better"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streetlight_effect).

Comment: @agc awk is a valid tool to this kind of problems. Adding the tag attracted more answers, which is beneficial to OP.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs I like your answer more, but I cannot find it now.

Comment: @ClintonLam Deleted it, because I think you should go for αғsнιη's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised less ugly `sed` method:

```
sed 's/^.*,"\|",.*//g;h;s#.*#date "+%Y/%m/%d %T" -d "&"#e;H;g;s#\n\|$#,#g;s/^/s,/' input.csv | sed -f - input.csv
```

Spread out, (it works the same):

```
sed 's/^.*,"\|",.*//g
     h;
     s#.*#date "+%Y/%m/%d %T" -d "&"#e;
     H;
     g;
     s#\n\|$#,#g;
     s/^/s,/' input.csv | sed -f - input.csv
```

Output:

```
"item1","2017/10/11 14:10:00",1,2, ...
"item2","2017/10/12 15:10:00",3,4, ...
```

---

How it works:

The first `sed` block uses the ***e***valuate command to run `date`, the output of which is used to generate some new `sed` ***s***ubstitute commands.  To show the new ***s*** commands, temporarily replace the shell script `|` pipe with a `#` comment:

```
s,10/11/2017 2:10pm,2017/10/11 14:10:00,
s,10/12/2017 3:10pm,2017/10/12 15:10:00,
```

These are piped to the second `sed`.

Comment: I don't think any one-liner for this problem will be 'pretty', but I like both or your and Marc's solutions which even a `sed` with 5 sub-expressions or the single `awk` solution are likely to be quicker than the combination of the two.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Code that generates brute force code is often not too speedy, but sometimes it's easier/faster to code.  But it's relevant to the OP's question about how to run `date` via `sed` (or *GNU* `sed` anyway).  I'm thinking my `printf` can be removed, (as well as the backquotes around `date`), with an abler use of `sed` commands...

Comment: I suspect you are correct. I would rather a single call to `sed` or `awk` over the mixed brute force approach. I'm still tinkering with `awk` to get rid of `expr`. But since we know it is always the 2nd field a single `sed` that looks for the first `,"` and captures `\([^"]*\)` as a back-reference would handle that which would then simply need the conversion to the new date format and substitute in place. Heck of a one-liner....

Comment: This is quite an art! There is so much for me to learn. Thank you.

Comment: @agc A small fix, in `s#.*#date "+%Y/%M/%d %T" -d &#e;` `%M` should be `%m` instead.

Answer (score 3):

One-liner `awk` approach.

```
awk -F',' '{gsub(/"/,"",$2); cmd="date -d\""$2"\" +\\\"%Y/%m/%d\\ %T\\\"";
    cmd |getline $2; close(cmd) }1' OFS=, infile #>>outfile
"item1","2017/10/11 14:10:00",1,2, ...
"item2","2017/10/12 15:10:00",3,4, ...
```

This will output changes in your Terminal, you need to redirect the output to a file if you need record the output or use `FILENAME` to redirect the output to the input `infile` itself.

```
awk -F',' '{gsub(/"/,"",$2); cmd="date -d\""$2"\" +\\\"%Y/%m/%d\\ %T\\\"";
    cmd |getline $2; close(cmd); print >FILENAME }' OFS=, infile
```

Or with GNU `awk` implementations which does support `-i inplace` identifier for in-place replace. see ['awk' save modifications in place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/4023950)

Comment: However, you do have a large problem. You are losing the quotation marks around the fields. See if that can be corrected.

Comment: @ClintonLam No, this works on a file called `infile`. Checked it myself. And about the quotes, I wouldn't mind those, because your csv doesn't seem to have any. If it does, this can be fixed. αғsнιη, take it away.

Comment: `"item1","10/11/2017 2:10pm",77.300,14127044,23190700,77.700,77.320,77.300,77.750,56.600,79.650,76.127,71.239,142.415,36.709,0.000,,1575.53B,"A"`

`"item2","10/12/2017 3:10pm",192.200,614721,942324,190.800,190.400,190.100,192.200,136.200,195.300,183.516,168.717,23.157,12.046,0.000,,367.49B,"B"`

Failed on this set of text, only two rows here, date of 2nd row not replaced.

Comment: please see my update, @DavidC.Rankin that's corrected.

Comment: @αғsнιη Yes, only 3 terms with quotes. But still, only 1st row was converted, all rows after that does not changes.

Comment: it works without any problem, please check your input file I for valid date in second column. Please avoid commenting clarifications here and directly [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46782016/edit) and update into your question. Thanks

Comment: @αғsнιη Great job. This would be much more efficient than a blended shell, awk, sed solution. I have got to work with awk more...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line, but that begs the question -- "How long of a line do you want?" Since you have it labeled `'shell'` and not bash, etc., you are a bit limited in your string handling. POSIX shell provides enough to do what you want, but it isn't the speediest remedy. You are either going to end up with an `awk` or `sed` solution that calls `date` or a shell solution that calls `awk` or `sed` to parse old date from the original file and feeds the result to `date` to get your new date. You will have to work out which provides the most efficient remedy.

As far as the one-liner goes, you can do something similar to the following while remaining POSIX compliant. It simply uses `awk` to get the 2nd `field` from the file, pipes the result to a `while` loop which uses `expr length "$field"` to get the length and uses that within `expr substr "$field" "2" <length expression - 2>` to chop the double-quotes from the end of the original date `olddt`, followed by `date -d "$olddt" +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'` to get `newdt` and finally `sed -i "s;$olddt;$newdt;"` to perform the substitution in place. Your one-liner (shown with auto line-continuations for readability)

```
$ awk -F, '{print $2}' timefile.txt | 
while read -r field; do 
olddt="$(expr substr "$field" "2" "$(($(expr length "$field") - 2))")"; 
newdt=$(date -d "$olddt" +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'); 
sed -i "s;$olddt;$newdt;" timefile.txt; done
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat timefile.txt
"item1","10/11/2017 2:10pm",1,2, ...
"item2","10/12/2017 3:10pm",3,4, ...
```

**Resulting File**

```
$ cat timefile.txt
"item1","2017/10/11 14:10:00",1,2, ...
"item2","2017/10/12 15:10:00",3,4, ...
```

There are probably faster ways to do it, but this is a reasonable length one-liner (relatively speaking).