# Need regular expression for sed

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to create a script that will amnog other things enable source repositories in sources.list (Ubuntu). As you may or may not know the format of the repository file is something like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# etc.
```

So I would like to enable source repository (uncomment lines with deb-src) but only for those preceded by the uncommented deb line. [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) should be perfect for this but I'm not able to make this work.
This is what I have right now:

```sh
sed -i 's/^# deb-src/deb-src/gm' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

What I would like to have is something like this but it should replace only the commented line not everything:

```sh
sed -i 's/^deb .*$^# deb-src/deb-src/gm' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

So is there a way to make regex for sed that will only replace a part of matched string?

Comment: In the default sources.list there are several entries where both deb and deb-src lines are commented. In those cases I want them to remain commented.

Comment: Ah, now I see it. My bad.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed?

Comment: I don't see it as relevant to my question.

Comment: I don't  see what your problem is. Doesn't it work?

Comment: @DarkoMiletic You'll need to match the newline somehow. E.g. `s/^deb (.*)<newline># deb-src \1/…/g`

Comment: In the replace mode sed replaces COMPLETE matched string with supplied one. So if I have 's/^deb .*$^# deb-src/deb-src/gm' it will replace the complete deb line and deb-src line with uncommented deb-src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-z` in addition to `-r`:

```
sed -rz -i 's/^(deb .*\s+)^# deb-src/\1deb-src/gm' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Capturing groups are necessary in order to refer to them in replacement.

Comment: That's it :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer `awk/perl` for matching two consecutive lines

```
awk '/^# *deb-src/ && p ~ /^deb /{sub(/^# */, "")} {p=$0} 1'
```

- `p=$0` saves previous line
- `/^# *deb-src/ && p ~ /^deb /` if current line starts with comment and has **deb-src** and previous line starts with **deb**
- `sub(/^# */, "")` remove comment
- `1` idiomatic way to print current record, including any changes made
- See also: [awk save modifications in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place)

With `sed`, you might need something like

```
sed '/^deb /{n; /^# *deb-src/ s/# *//p; D}'
```

or

```
sed '$!N; /^deb .*\n# *deb-src/ s/\n# */\n/p; D'
```

but I'm not very sure if this would handle all cases. See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#advanced-sed for details. The `m` modifier comes into play only if you have multiple lines in pattern space. By default, `sed` uses newline as line separator and only has single line in pattern space. The manual link has more details

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response but I prefer the answer provided by user @revo.

Answer (score 0):

If your sources.list is only composed of lines like:

```
deb http://................
deb-src http://............

# deb http://...........
# deb-src http://.........

deb http://................
# deb-src http://............
```

And you don't care of removing the commented lines, you can create dinamically a new sources.list file by modifying only the lines after the ones starting by `deb` that are not commented:

```
grep -A1 "^deb " sources.list | sed "s/# deb-src/deb-src/g"
```

With this you grep only the lines starting by `^deb` and the following one, and then you uncomment the next line (the one starting by `# deb-src`)

You can then send the output to a new file which can be renamed by sources.list afterwards:

```
grep -A1 "^deb " sources.list | sed "s/# deb-src/deb-src/g" > sources_new && mv -f sources_new sources.list
```

But this will only work if you have this exact syntax in your sources.list file.