# Add a new column with Line number to a pipe delimited file

Tags: macos, awk, terminal

I am really struggling to add a new column with the line number in the terminal to a pipe delimited file

My current file looks like this:

```
ID|FirstName|LastName
12|John|Svernson
23|Mark|Wright
11|Chris|Watson
```

And I want the file to look like the following:

```
LN|ID|FirstName|LastName
1|12|John|Svernson
2|23|Mark|Wright
3|11|Chris|Watson
```

I have over 90k lines. I couldn't find a way to do this. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Strip the header and pipe the data to `nl -ba -s\|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print "LN|"$0;next} {$1=++count "|" $1} 1'   Input_file
```

To write output into Input_file itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` in above code too.

Comment: @Nant, please see my update for saving output into Input_file itself one.

Comment: You need to do smth with the header because it becomes wrong and shifted

Comment: @CorentinLimier, cool thanks for letting me know edited it now(along with saving output into Input_file too).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A fun alternative:

```
{ echo LN; seq $(( $(wc -l < file) - 1 )); } | paste -d'|' - file
```

although in reality I'd use

```
awk '{print (NR==1 ? "LN" : NR-1), $0}' OFS="|" file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use awk variable NR (record number):

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1{print "LN" FS $0}NR!=1{print NR-1 FS $0}' file
```

Comment: thanks for this but this doesn't actually write this in the file right? It's just prints it out? Is there a way to save this in the file?

Comment: @Nant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place

Answer (score 0):

I would use `nl`.  You may run into issues if your line number goes over 6 digits, but you can add a `-w` to increase the number width if you need to:

```
   { read line; echo "LN|$line"; cat | nl -w 10 -ba -s \|; } < input | 
       sed 's/^ *//';
```